# Preserving signatures of decorated functions

Tags: python, decorator

Suppose I have written a decorator that does something very generic. For example, it might convert all arguments to a specific type, perform logging, implement memoization, etc.

Here is an example:

```
def args_as_ints(f):
    def g(*args, **kwargs):
        args = [int(x) for x in args]
        kwargs = dict((k, int(v)) for k, v in kwargs.items())
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return g

@args_as_ints
def funny_function(x, y, z=3):
    """Computes x*y + 2*z"""
    return x*y + 2*z

>>> funny_function("3", 4.0, z="5")
22
```

Everything well so far. There is one problem, however. The decorated function does not retain the documentation of the original function:

```
>>> help(funny_function)
Help on function g in module __main__:

g(*args, **kwargs)
```

Fortunately, there is a workaround:

```
def args_as_ints(f):
    def g(*args, **kwargs):
        args = [int(x) for x in args]
        kwargs = dict((k, int(v)) for k, v in kwargs.items())
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    g.__name__ = f.__name__
    g.__doc__ = f.__doc__
    return g

@args_as_ints
def funny_function(x, y, z=3):
    """Computes x*y + 2*z"""
    return x*y + 2*z
```

This time, the function name and documentation are correct:

```
>>> help(funny_function)
Help on function funny_function in module __main__:

funny_function(*args, **kwargs)
    Computes x*y + 2*z
```

But there is still a problem: the function signature is wrong. The information "*args, **kwargs" is next to useless.

What to do? I can think of two simple but flawed workarounds:

1 -- Include the correct signature in the docstring:

```
def funny_function(x, y, z=3):
    """funny_function(x, y, z=3) -- computes x*y + 2*z"""
    return x*y + 2*z
```

This is bad because of the duplication. The signature will still not be shown properly in automatically generated documentation. It's easy to update the function and forget about changing the docstring, or to make a typo. [*And yes, I'm aware of the fact that the docstring already duplicates the function body. Please ignore this; funny_function is just a random example.*]

2 -- Not use a decorator, or use a special-purpose decorator for every specific signature:

```
def funny_functions_decorator(f):
    def g(x, y, z=3):
        return f(int(x), int(y), z=int(z))
    g.__name__ = f.__name__
    g.__doc__ = f.__doc__
    return g
```

This works fine for a set of functions that have identical signature, but it's useless in general. As I said in the beginning, I want to be able to use decorators entirely generically.

I'm looking for a solution that is fully general, and automatic.

So the question is: is there a way to edit the decorated function signature after it has been created?

Otherwise, can I write a decorator that extracts the function signature and uses that information instead of "*kwargs, **kwargs" when constructing the decorated function? How do I extract that information? How should I construct the decorated function -- with exec?

Any other approaches?

Comment: Never said "out of date". I was more or less wondering what `inspect.Signature` added to dealing with decorated functions.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

1. Install [decorator](http://www.phyast.pitt.edu/~micheles/python/documentation.html#the-solution) module:

   ```
   $ pip install decorator
   ```
2. Adapt definition of `args_as_ints()`:

   ```
   import decorator

   @decorator.decorator
   def args_as_ints(f, *args, **kwargs):
       args = [int(x) for x in args]
       kwargs = dict((k, int(v)) for k, v in kwargs.items())
       return f(*args, **kwargs)

   @args_as_ints
   def funny_function(x, y, z=3):
       """Computes x*y + 2*z"""
       return x*y + 2*z

   print funny_function("3", 4.0, z="5")
   # 22
   help(funny_function)
   # Help on function funny_function in module __main__:
   # 
   # funny_function(x, y, z=3)
   #     Computes x*y + 2*z
   ```

---

#### Python 3.4+

[`functools.wraps()` from stdlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) preserves signatures since Python 3.4:

```
import functools


def args_as_ints(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        args = [int(x) for x in args]
        kwargs = dict((k, int(v)) for k, v in kwargs.items())
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@args_as_ints
def funny_function(x, y, z=3):
    """Computes x*y + 2*z"""
    return x*y + 2*z


print(funny_function("3", 4.0, z="5"))
# 22
help(funny_function)
# Help on function funny_function in module __main__:
#
# funny_function(x, y, z=3)
#     Computes x*y + 2*z
```

`functools.wraps()` is available [at least since Python 2.5](https://docs.python.org/2.5/lib/module-functools.html) but it does not preserve the signature there:

```
help(funny_function)
# Help on function funny_function in module __main__:
#
# funny_function(*args, **kwargs)
#    Computes x*y + 2*z
```

Notice: `*args, **kwargs` instead of `x, y, z=3`.

Comment: Yours wasn't the first answer, but the most comprehensive so far :-)

I would actually prefer a solution not involving a third party module, but looking at the source for the decorator module, it's simple enough that I'll be able to just copy it.

Comment: To preserve the signature, additionally set `wrapper.__signature__ = inspect.signature(func)` before returning `wrapper`.

Comment: @MarkLodato: `functools.wraps()` already preserves signatures in Python 3.4+ (as said in the answer). Do you mean setting `wrapper.__signature__` helps on earlier versions? (which versions have you tested?)

Comment: Ah, sorry.  `inspect.signature` is not available in Python 2 so it won't help.  In Python 3.4, `functools.wraps()` does not set `__signature__` so the signature does not show up properly in IPython.  Setting it explicitly fixes the issue.  So this doesn't solve the OP's problem, but it did solve mine.

Comment: @MarkLodato: `help()` shows the correct signature on Python 3.4. Why do you think `functools.wraps()` is broken and not IPython?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: `functools.wraps()` is not broken, but older versions of IPython3 don't pick up the signature unless you set `__signature__`.  For example, the latest version in Ubuntu (1.2.1) requires `__signature__` to be set, while it works in 3.2.1 from pip.  See https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3d97523517abe0f55dc9.

Comment: @MarkLodato: it is broken if we have to write code to fix it. Given that `help()` produces the correct result, the question is what piece of software should be fixed: `functools.wraps()` or IPython? In any case, manually assigning `__signature__` is a workaround at best -- it is not a long-term solution.

Comment: Looks like `inspect.getfullargspec()` still doesn't return proper signature for `functools.wraps` in python 3.4 and that you must use `inspect.signature()` instead.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "preserve signature": appearance or behavior. As of python 3.7, `functools.wraps` still does not preserve the behavior (`TypeError` in case of wrong arguments). See detailed answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55163816/7262247

Answer (score 29):

This is solved with Python's standard library `functools` and specifically [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) function, which is designed to "*update a wrapper function to look like the wrapped function*". It's behaviour depends on Python version, however, as shown below. Applied to the example from the question, the code would look like:

```
from functools import wraps

def args_as_ints(f):
    @wraps(f) 
    def g(*args, **kwargs):
        args = [int(x) for x in args]
        kwargs = dict((k, int(v)) for k, v in kwargs.items())
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return g


@args_as_ints
def funny_function(x, y, z=3):
    """Computes x*y + 2*z"""
    return x*y + 2*z
```

When executed in Python 3, this would produce the following:

```
>>> funny_function("3", 4.0, z="5")
22
>>> help(funny_function)
Help on function funny_function in module __main__:

funny_function(x, y, z=3)
    Computes x*y + 2*z
```

Its only drawback is that in Python 2 however, it doesn't update function's argument list. When executed in Python 2, it will produce:

```
>>> help(funny_function)
Help on function funny_function in module __main__:

funny_function(*args, **kwargs)
    Computes x*y + 2*z
```

Comment: Not sure if it's Sphinx, but this doesn't seem to work when the wrapped function is a method of a class. Sphinx continues to report the call signature of the decorator.

Comment: `functools.wraps` is incomplete. `inspect.getfullargspec(func)` still returns the signature of the decorator function instead of the wrapped function.

Answer (score 9):

There is a [decorator module](http://www.phyast.pitt.edu/~micheles/python/documentation.html) with `decorator` decorator you can use:

```
@decorator
def args_as_ints(f, *args, **kwargs):
    args = [int(x) for x in args]
    kwargs = dict((k, int(v)) for k, v in kwargs.items())
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then the signature and help of the method is preserved:

```
>>> help(funny_function)
Help on function funny_function in module __main__:

funny_function(x, y, z=3)
    Computes x*y + 2*z
```

EDIT: J. F. Sebastian pointed out that I didn't modify `args_as_ints` function -- it is fixed now.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at the [decorator](http://www.phyast.pitt.edu/~micheles/python/documentation.html) module - specifically the [decorator](http://www.phyast.pitt.edu/~micheles/python/documentation.html#decorator-is-a-decorator) decorator, which solves this problem.

Answer (score 6):

Second option:

1. Install wrapt module:

$ easy_install wrapt

wrapt have a bonus, preserve class signature.

```
import wrapt
import inspect
```

@wrapt.decorator
def args_as_ints(wrapped, instance, args, kwargs):
    if instance is None:
        if inspect.isclass(wrapped):
            # Decorator was applied to a class.
            return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            # Decorator was applied to a function or staticmethod.
            return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
        if inspect.isclass(instance):
            # Decorator was applied to a classmethod.
            return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            # Decorator was applied to an instancemethod.
            return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)


@args_as_ints
def funny_function(x, y, z=3):
    """Computes x*y + 2*z"""
    return x * y + 2 * z


>>> funny_function(3, 4, z=5))
# 22

>>> help(funny_function)
Help on function funny_function in module __main__:

funny_function(x, y, z=3)
    Computes x*y + 2*z

Answer (score 4):

As commented above in [jfs's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/147878/7262247) ; if you're concerned with signature in terms of appearance (`help`, and `inspect.signature`), then using `functools.wraps` is perfectly fine.

If you're concerned with signature in terms of behavior (in particular `TypeError` in case of arguments mismatch), `functools.wraps` does not preserve it. You should rather use `decorator` for that, or my generalization of its core engine, named [`makefun`](https://smarie.github.io/python-makefun/).

```
from makefun import wraps

def args_as_ints(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("wrapper executes")
        args = [int(x) for x in args]
        kwargs = dict((k, int(v)) for k, v in kwargs.items())
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@args_as_ints
def funny_function(x, y, z=3):
    """Computes x*y + 2*z"""
    return x*y + 2*z


print(funny_function("3", 4.0, z="5"))
# wrapper executes
# 22

help(funny_function)
# Help on function funny_function in module __main__:
#
# funny_function(x, y, z=3)
#     Computes x*y + 2*z

funny_function(0)  
# observe: no "wrapper executes" is printed! (with functools it would)
# TypeError: funny_function() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

See also [this post about `functools.wraps`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55102697/7262247).

Comment: Also, the result of `inspect.getfullargspec` is not kept by calling `functools.wraps`.

Comment: Thanks for the useful additional comment @laike9m !

Answer (score 3):

```
from inspect import signature


def args_as_ints(f):
    def g(*args, **kwargs):
        args = [int(x) for x in args]
        kwargs = dict((k, int(v)) for k, v in kwargs.items())
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    sig = signature(f)
    g.__signature__ = sig
    g.__doc__ = f.__doc__
    g.__annotations__ = f.__annotations__
    g.__name__ = f.__name__
    return g

@args_as_ints
def funny_function(x, y, z=3):
    """Computes x*y + 2*z"""
    return x*y + 2*z

>>> funny_function("3", 4.0, z="5")
22
```

I wanted to add that answer (since this shows up first in google). The inspect module is able to fetch the signature of a function, so that it can be preserved in decorators. But that's not all. If you want to modify the signature, you can do so like this :

```
from inspect import signature, Parameter, _ParameterKind


def foo(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b

sig = signature(foo)
sig._parameters = dict(sig.parameters)
sig.parameters['c'] = Parameter(
    'c', _ParameterKind.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD, 
    annotation=int
)
foo.__signature__ = sig

>>> help(foo)
Help on function foo in module __main__:

foo(a: int, b: int, c: int) -> int
```

Why would you want to mutate a function's signature ?

It's mostly useful to have adequate documentation on your functions and methods. If you're using the `*args, **kwargs` syntax and then popping arguments from kwargs for other uses in your decorators, that keyword argument won't be properly documented, hence, modifying the signature of the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
def args_as_ints(f):
    def g(*args, **kwargs):
        args = [int(x) for x in args]
        kwargs = dict((k, int(v)) for k, v in kwargs.items())
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    g.__name__ = f.__name__
    g.__doc__ = f.__doc__
    return g
```

this fixes name and documentation. to preserve the function signature, `wrap` is used exactly at same location as `g.__name__ = f.__name__, g.__doc__ = f.__doc__`.

the `wraps` itself a decorator. we pass the closure-the inner function to that decorator, and it is going to fix up the metadata. BUt if we only pass in the inner function to `wraps`, it is not gonna know where to copy the metadata from. It needs to know which function's metadata needs to be protected. It needs to know the original function.

```
def args_as_ints(f):
    def g(*args, **kwargs):
        args = [int(x) for x in args]
        kwargs = dict((k, int(v)) for k, v in kwargs.items())
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    g=wraps(f)(g)
    return g
```

`wraps(f)` is going to return a function which will take `g` as its parameter. And that is going to return closure and will assigned to `g` and then we return it.