# How can I read a function's signature including default argument values?

Tags: python, arguments, inspect

Given a function object, how can I get its signature? For example, for:

```
def my_method(first, second, third='something'):
    pass
```

I would like to get `"my_method(first, second, third='something')"`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your specific question and maybe give an example with the expected result?

Comment: Presumably he's looking for functionality in Python or third-party libraries that will return a method's signature (names and types of parameters and return value) given the method's name.

Comment: Signature as in how to call it and such?  Try `help(yourmethod)`
e.g. `help(map)`

Comment: Just parameters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218616/getting-method-parameter-names-in-python

Answer (score 262, accepted):

```
import inspect

def foo(a, b, x='blah'):
    pass

print(inspect.signature(foo))
# (a, b, x='blah')
```

Python 3.5+ recommends [`inspect.signature()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature).

Comment: @Spi, you are calling `inspect.getargspec` on a module, not a function.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was with Eclipse that did not see the inspect module

Comment: If a function has argument annotations or keyword only arguments (= if you are using Python 3) you have to call `getfullargspec` instead. (`ValueError: Function has keyword-only arguments or annotations, use getfullargspec() API which can support them`)

Comment: @unutbu , I tried the same on `Exception.__init__` but got an error `TypeError: <slot wrapper '__init__' of 'exceptions.Exception' objects> is not a Python function`. Any help on how can we get the signature of functions of types.

Comment: @darth_coder: In Python2, `getargspec` raises `TypeError` if the input is not recognized as a *Python* function -- that is, a function implemented in Python. In CPython, `Exception.__init__` is implemented in C, hence the `TypeError`. You'll have to check the source code to understand the call signature. In Python3, `getargspec` is implemented differently, and there `inspect.getargspec(Exception.__init__)` returns a `ArgSpec` instance.

Comment: is there a way to extract the list of possible values for each argument as well?

Comment: I am not getting the proper info... `<function fread at 0x7f660eb6d158>`

Answer (score 61):

Arguably the easiest way to find the signature for a function would be `help(function)`:

```
>>> def function(arg1, arg2="foo", *args, **kwargs): pass
>>> help(function)
Help on function function in module __main__:

function(arg1, arg2='foo', *args, **kwargs)
```

Also, in Python 3 a method was added to the `inspect` module called `signature`, which is designed to represent the [signature of a callable object and its return annotation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature):

```
>>> from inspect import signature
>>> def foo(a, *, b:int, **kwargs):
...     pass

>>> sig = signature(foo)

>>> str(sig)
'(a, *, b:int, **kwargs)'

>>> str(sig.parameters['b'])
'b:int'

>>> sig.parameters['b'].annotation
<class 'int'>
```

Comment: `inspect.signature` is also available for Python 2 via the `funcsigs` backport project: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/funcsigs

Comment: What's the difference between `inspect.signature` and `typing.get_type_hints`?

Comment: Use `inspect.signature(func).parameters.keys()` if you want a list of the parameters.

Answer (score 15):

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python

import inspect
from collections import namedtuple

DefaultArgSpec = namedtuple('DefaultArgSpec', 'has_default default_value')

def _get_default_arg(args, defaults, arg_index):
    """ Method that determines if an argument has default value or not,
    and if yes what is the default value for the argument

    :param args: array of arguments, eg: ['first_arg', 'second_arg', 'third_arg']
    :param defaults: array of default values, eg: (42, 'something')
    :param arg_index: index of the argument in the argument array for which,
    this function checks if a default value exists or not. And if default value
    exists it would return the default value. Example argument: 1
    :return: Tuple of whether there is a default or not, and if yes the default
    value, eg: for index 2 i.e. for "second_arg" this function returns (True, 42)
    """
    if not defaults:
        return DefaultArgSpec(False, None)

    args_with_no_defaults = len(args) - len(defaults)

    if arg_index < args_with_no_defaults:
        return DefaultArgSpec(False, None)
    else:
        value = defaults[arg_index - args_with_no_defaults]
        if (type(value) is str):
            value = '"%s"' % value
        return DefaultArgSpec(True, value)

def get_method_sig(method):
    """ Given a function, it returns a string that pretty much looks how the
    function signature would be written in python.

    :param method: a python method
    :return: A string similar describing the pythong method signature.
    eg: "my_method(first_argArg, second_arg=42, third_arg='something')"
    """

    # The return value of ArgSpec is a bit weird, as the list of arguments and
    # list of defaults are returned in separate array.
    # eg: ArgSpec(args=['first_arg', 'second_arg', 'third_arg'],
    # varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=(42, 'something'))
    argspec = inspect.getargspec(method)
    arg_index=0
    args = []

    # Use the args and defaults array returned by argspec and find out
    # which arguments has default
    for arg in argspec.args:
        default_arg = _get_default_arg(argspec.args, argspec.defaults, arg_index)
        if default_arg.has_default:
            args.append("%s=%s" % (arg, default_arg.default_value))
        else:
            args.append(arg)
        arg_index += 1
    return "%s(%s)" % (method.__name__, ", ".join(args))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    def my_method(first_arg, second_arg=42, third_arg='something'):
        pass

    print get_method_sig(my_method)
    # my_method(first_argArg, second_arg=42, third_arg="something")
```

Comment: Any explanation at all as to what this is supposed to do?

Comment: Added comments to the code sample, hope that helps.

Comment: Lovely stuff. Would be even better if you could adjust it to work with `def foo(a, *, b:int, **kwargs)` called with `foo(4, b=3.3)`

Answer (score 11):

Try calling `help` on an object to find out about it.

```
>>> foo = [1, 2, 3]
>>> help(foo.append)
Help on built-in function append:

append(...)
    L.append(object) -- append object to end
```

Answer (score 8):

Maybe a bit late to the party, but if you also want to keep the order of the arguments *and their defaults*, then you can use the [Abstract Syntax Tree module (ast)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html).

Here's a proof of concept (beware the code to sort the arguments and match them to their defaults can definitely be improved/made more clear):

```
import ast

for class_ in [c for c in module.body if isinstance(c, ast.ClassDef)]:
    for method in [m for m in class_.body if isinstance(m, ast.FunctionDef)]:
        args = []
        if method.args.args:
            [args.append([a.col_offset, a.id]) for a in method.args.args]
        if method.args.defaults:
            [args.append([a.col_offset, '=' + a.id]) for a in method.args.defaults]
        sorted_args = sorted(args)
        for i, p in enumerate(sorted_args):
            if p[1].startswith('='):
                sorted_args[i-1][1] += p[1]
        sorted_args = [k[1] for k in sorted_args if not k[1].startswith('=')]

        if method.args.vararg:
            sorted_args.append('*' + method.args.vararg)
        if method.args.kwarg:
            sorted_args.append('**' + method.args.kwarg)

        signature = '(' + ', '.join(sorted_args) + ')'

        print method.name + signature
```

Comment: Note that [non-default arguments cannot follow default arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16932825/1143274), so we can simply match them up from the tail?

Answer (score 7):

If all you're trying to do is print the function then use pydoc.

```
import pydoc    

def foo(arg1, arg2, *args, **kwargs):                                                                    
    '''Some foo fn'''                                                                                    
    pass                                                                                                 

>>> print pydoc.render_doc(foo).splitlines()[2]
foo(arg1, arg2, *args, **kwargs)
```

If you're trying to actually analyze the function signature then use argspec of the inspection module. I had to do that when validating a user's hook script function into a general framework.

Answer (score 7):

Use %pdef in the command line (IPython), it will print only the signature.

e.g. `%pdef np.loadtxt`

```
 np.loadtxt(fname, dtype=<class 'float'>, comments='#', delimiter=None, converters=None, skiprows=0, usecols=None, unpack=False, ndmin=0, encoding='bytes')
```

Answer (score 6):

Example code:

```
import inspect
from collections import OrderedDict


def get_signature(fn):
    params = inspect.signature(fn).parameters
    args = []
    kwargs = OrderedDict()
    for p in params.values():
        if p.default is p.empty:
            args.append(p.name)
        else:
            kwargs[p.name] = p.default
    return args, kwargs


def test_sig():
    def fn(a, b, c, d=3, e="abc"):
        pass

    assert get_signature(fn) == (
        ["a", "b", "c"], OrderedDict([("d", 3), ("e", "abc")])
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Another late entry.  My point isn't to, again, print the sig, or display help.  It is to **programmatically introspect function parameters** (when I got to this question I was looking to check Django view functions by looking at functions with `request` as a first parameter name).

The key is the [Signature.parameters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Parameter) attribute, which is actually not that complicated (note that `inspect._empty` is akin to `None` in concept).

```
import inspect
from typing import Any, cast

def check_signature(func : "Callable") -> None:
    funcname = func.__name__
    try:
        # class inspect.Signature(parameters=None, *, return_annotation=Signature.empty)
        # see https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Signature
        sig = inspect.signature(func)
    except (ValueError,) as e: 
        print(f"\n\n`{funcname}` has no signature")
        return
    
    print(f"\n\n`{funcname}{sig}` parameters:")
    for position, (name,param) in enumerate(sig.parameters.items()):
        # class inspect.Parameter(name, kind, *, default=Parameter.empty, annotation=Parameter.empty)
        # see https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Parameter
        print(f"  {position} {name:30.30}  kind={param.kind.description.replace(' ','_')} / default={param.default if param.default is not inspect._empty else ''} / annotation={param.annotation if param.annotation is not inspect._empty else ''}")

class Foo:
    def bar(self, zoom : int =2):
        pass

for func in [Any, check_signature, print, Foo.bar, Foo().bar, isinstance, issubclass, cast]:
    check_signature(func)
```

#### output:

```
`Any(*args, **kwds)` parameters:
  0 args                            kind=variadic_positional / default= / annotation=
  1 kwds                            kind=variadic_keyword / default= / annotation=


`check_signature(func: 'Callable') -> None` parameters:
  0 func                            kind=positional_or_keyword / default= / annotation=Callable


`print` has no signature


`bar(self, zoom: int = 2)` parameters:
  0 self                            kind=positional_or_keyword / default= / annotation=
  1 zoom                            kind=positional_or_keyword / default=2 / annotation=<class 'int'>


`bar(zoom: int = 2)` parameters:
  0 zoom                            kind=positional_or_keyword / default=2 / annotation=<class 'int'>


`isinstance(obj, class_or_tuple, /)` parameters:
  0 obj                             kind=positional-only / default= / annotation=
  1 class_or_tuple                  kind=positional-only / default= / annotation=


`issubclass(cls, class_or_tuple, /)` parameters:
  0 cls                             kind=positional-only / default= / annotation=
  1 class_or_tuple                  kind=positional-only / default= / annotation=


`cast(typ, val)` parameters:
  0 typ                             kind=positional_or_keyword / default= / annotation=
  1 val                             kind=positional_or_keyword / default= / annotation=
```

In the OP's case you'd just check for `param.default is not inspect._empty`.  I'd opt for returning a `dict[str, Any]` of those.

To make things a bit easier on myself, I went and added a pydantic wrapper to the whole thing:

```
class FuncSignature(BaseModel):

    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True

    funcname: str
    sig : inspect.Signature
    by_pos : dict[int,inspect.Parameter]
    by_name: dict[str,inspect.Parameter]

    undefined = inspect._empty

def get_signature(func : "Callable") -> FuncSignature:
    """return signature for a function"""
    funcname = func.__name__
    sig = inspect.signature(func)
    by_name, by_pos = {},{}

    for position, (name,param) in enumerate(sig.parameters.items()):
        by_name[name] = param
        by_pos[position] = param

    return FuncSignature(funcname=funcname, sig=sig,by_name=by_name,by_pos=by_pos)
```

which allowed me to

```
def myview(request, rdbname):
    pass

res = check_signature(myview)
print(res.by_pos[0].name == "request")  # True
```