# Get Keyword Arguments for Function, Python

Tags: python, function, introspection

```
def thefunction(a=1,b=2,c=3):
    pass

print allkeywordsof(thefunction) #allkeywordsof doesnt exist
```

which would give [a,b,c]

Is there a function like allkeywordsof?

I cant change anything inside, `thefunction`

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677185/how-read-method-signature

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting method parameter names in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218616/getting-method-parameter-names-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this:

```
>>> def func(x,y,z,a=1,b=2,c=3):
    pass

>>> func.func_code.co_varnames[-len(func.func_defaults):]
('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Comment: co_varnames is a wrong decision, it also holds non-keyword arguments and topic-starter wants only keyword arguments

Comment: @RostyslavDzinko yeah you're right, but the problem is `inspect.getargspec()` also returns non-keyword arguments.

Comment: @user1513192 This one is bad because it doesn't use inspect. It's better to use libraries in Python as they are designed for that use.

Comment: @user1513192, this answer doesn't fix the problem you described. If it fits your needs - redescribe your problem (My upper comment shows why)

Comment: `def thefunction(foo, a=1,b=2,c=3):
    pass` Doesn't work. Should return `('a', 'b', 'c')`

Comment: @jamylak used this because I haven't learned `inspect` yet and will surely learn it now. :)

Comment: In python 3 `func_code` has been renamed to `__code__`.

Comment: `func.__code__.co_varnames` also returns local variables.

Answer (score 24):

I think you are looking for [inspect.getargspec](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec):

```
import inspect

def thefunction(a=1,b=2,c=3):
    pass

argspec = inspect.getargspec(thefunction)
print(argspec.args)
```

yields

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

---

If your function contains both positional and keyword arguments, then finding the names of the keyword arguments is a bit more complicated, but not too hard:

```
def thefunction(pos1, pos2, a=1,b=2,c=3, *args, **kwargs):
    pass

argspec = inspect.getargspec(thefunction)

print(argspec)
# ArgSpec(args=['pos1', 'pos2', 'a', 'b', 'c'], varargs='args', keywords='kwargs', defaults=(1, 2, 3))

print(argspec.args)
# ['pos1', 'pos2', 'a', 'b', 'c']

print(argspec.args[-len(argspec.defaults):])
# ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: How can I make it give me the agrs only

Comment: `inspect.getargspec(thefunction).args`

Comment: `argspec.args[-len(argspec.defaults):]` this should be accepted because it answers the question.

Comment: No disrespect to the OP or Ashwini, but I agree this should really be the accepted answer for future references...

Comment: `getargspec` has [been deprecated since v3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec), use `getfullargspec` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following in order to get exactly what you are looking for.

```
>>> 
>>> def funct(a=1,b=2,c=3):
...     pass
... 
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getargspec(funct)[0]
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>>
```