# How to get keyword arguments for a function

Tags: python, metaprogramming

```
>>> def test(arg1, arg2, arg3=None): pass
>>> test.func_code.co_varnames
('arg1', 'arg2, 'arg3')
```

What I want is something like:

```
{'args': ('arg1', 'arg2'), 'kwargs': {'arg3': None}}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: *All* fixed arguments are valid targets for a keyword argument.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Keyword Arguments for Function, Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915032/get-keyword-arguments-for-function-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`inspect.getargspec()`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec) to get the arguments a function expects.

```
>>> inspect.getargspec(test)
ArgSpec(args=['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'], varargs=None, keywords=None,
        defaults=(None,))
```

As you can see the `keywords` attribute is `None` as any argument can be passed as a kwarg; it would contain the name of the `**kwargs` argument if one existed.

To get a dict mapping the argument names to default values you can use this code with `as` being the ArgSpec returned by `inspect.getargspec()`:

```
defaults = dict(zip(*[reversed(l) for l in (as.args, as.defaults or [])]))
```