# Why can't non-default arguments follow default arguments?

Tags: python, keyword-argument, positional-argument

Why does this piece of code throw a SyntaxError?

```
>>> def fun1(a="who is you", b="True", x, y):
...     print a,b,x,y
... 
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument
```

While the following piece of code runs without visible errors:

```
>>> def fun1(x, y, a="who is you", b="True"):
...     print a,b,x,y
...
```

Comment: in python that is how the structure is when you define a function
`def myfunction(position_arguments, *arguments, **keywords):`
`    ....`

Comment: There is no sensible answer to this when it comes to KEYWORD-ONLY arguments - why can't default and non-default keyword-only arguments be mixed? They're keyword, so their order shouldn't really matter. This IS an arbitrary limitation.

Answer (score 208, accepted):

All required parameters must be placed before any default arguments. Simply because they are mandatory, whereas default arguments are not. Syntactically, it would be *impossible* for the interpreter to decide which values match which arguments if mixed modes were allowed. A `SyntaxError` is raised if the arguments are not given in the correct order:

Let us take a look at keyword arguments, using your function.

```
def fun1(a="who is you", b="True", x, y):
...     print a,b,x,y
```

Suppose its allowed to declare function as above,
Then with the above declarations, we can make the following (regular) positional or keyword argument calls:

```
func1("ok a", "ok b", 1)  # Is 1 assigned to x or ?
func1(1)                  # Is 1 assigned to a or ?
func1(1, 2)               # ?
```

How you will suggest the assignment of variables in the function call, how default arguments are going to be used along with keyword arguments.

```
>>> def fun1(x, y, a="who is you", b="True"):
...     print a,b,x,y
...
```

*Reference O'Reilly - Core-Python*
                                                               Where as this function make use of the default arguments syntactically correct for above function calls.
Keyword arguments calling prove useful for being able to provide for out-of-order positional arguments, but, coupled with default arguments, they can also be used to "skip over" missing arguments as well.

Comment: <q>Syntactically, it would be impossible for the interpreter to decide which values match which arguments if mixed modes were allowed.</q>  Ruby allows non-default arguments following default ones. <q>How you will suggest the assignment of variables in the function call</q> Just use `func1(x=1, y=2)`.

Comment: Hi @weakish, thanks for the comment, Python does have a nice way to achieve this, Please go search for *args and **kwargs

Comment: Hi @Rahul Gautam I'm confused. I thought `**kwargs` can not make `def fun1(a="who is you", b="True", x, y)` or similar work. If you use `def f(**kwargs)`, you need to handle default values in the body?

Comment: @weakish `def fun1(a="who is you", b="True", x, y)` the same thing be achieved with a different style. if def fun1(**kwrgs)` then call `fun1({'a': 'who is you', 'b': True})` no need to pass x and y.

Comment: Why do you write" Syntactically, it would be impossible for the interpreter to decide which values match which arguments if mixed modes were allowed."?

I think that the algorithm at [PEP 3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/#function-calling-behavior) could work exactly the same even if `def foo(x=None, y)` would be allowed.

So I'm still curious *why* this is not allowed by Python. Is there a real fundamental reason or is it just "we don't allow it because we don't allow it".

Comment: Hi @JeroenDemeyer, Sorry did not saw your comment earlier. Try to run below function through positional argument binding specified in PEP 3102. ```def f(x=1, y, z=2, a=2, b):``` You will find that it can not bind values to the variable. - Hence syntax error.   ```def foo(x=None, y)``` is a much simple example to run by :)

Comment: try with `def foo(a=1 ,b): called via foo(b=2)` and tell me where the pep throws, it is not the cause to forbid defaults before nondefaults i guess..

Comment: What do you mean "it would be impossible for the interpreter to decide which value ..."? For positional calls, the interpreter could simply match from left to right regardless of whether there is a default value or not.

Comment: with this `def func1(a="who is you", b="True", x, y):` function defination - calling it as `func1(1)` => what is the expectation @HanhanLi  => should 1 be assigned to a or x. if it is going to be assigned to `a` then what is the meaning of giving default value when I also have to pass both `a` and `b` values to the function in order to send value for `x`

Comment: @RahulGautam It will be assigned to a. Btw, you have to provide all 4 of them if you use positional calls. The defaults will still be useful when you make keyword calls, eg func1(x=1, y=2).

Answer (score 21):

```
SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument
```

If you were to allow this, the default arguments would be rendered useless because you would never be able to use their default values, since the non-default arguments  come **after**.

In Python 3 however, you may do the following:

```
def fun1(a="who is you", b="True", *, x, y):
    pass
```

which makes `x` and `y` keyword only so you can do this:

```
fun1(x=2, y=2)
```

This works because there is no longer any ambiguity. Note you still can't do `fun1(2, 2)` (that would set the default arguments).

Comment: Keyword-only arguments are a neat feature of Python 3. Too bad the patch to backport them to Python 2.6 and 2.7 was just [left to expire](http://bugs.python.org/issue1745).

Comment: This is not true: "If you were to allow this, the default arguments would be rendered useless because you would never be able to use their default values, since the non-default arguments come after."
Example: def foo(a=1 ,b): called via foo(b=2)

Answer (score 16):

Let me clear two points here :

- firstly non-default argument should not follow default argument , it means you can't define (a=b,c) in function the order of defining parameter in function are :

  - positional parameter or non-default parameter  i.e (a,b,c)
  - keyword parameter or default parameter         i.e (a="b",r="j")
  - keyword-only parameter                         i.e (*args)
  - var-keyword  parameter                         i.e (**kwargs)

`def example(a, b, c=None, r="w" , d=[], *ae,  **ab):`

(a,b) are positional parameter

(c=none) is optional parameter

(r="w") is keyword parameter

(d=[]) is list parameter

(*ae) is keyword-only

(**ab) is var-keyword parameter

- now secondary thing is if i try something like this :
  `def example(a, b, c=a,d=b):`

argument is not defined when default values are saved,Python computes
and saves default values when you define the function

c and d are not defined, does not exist, when this happens (it exists only when the function is executed)

"a,a=b" its not allowed in parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Required arguments (the ones without defaults), must be at the start to allow client code to only supply two.  If the optional arguments were at the start, it would be confusing:

```
fun1("who is who", 3, "jack")
```

What would that do in your first example?  In the last, x is "who is who", y is 3 and a = "jack".