# Python script to create custom printed material for a science fair booth

Tags: python

I'm currently set to run a booth at an upcoming science fair at my organization. The booth that I am helping with revolves around taking a manual process and automating it using Python.

All the booth are procuring their own "goodies" to give out as an incentive for people to visit their booth.

I thought it would be a fun idea to make custom [Koozies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koozie) that have a Python script which creates a function about whether or not a person should use a Koozie.

I basically want the function to do the following:

1. first assess whether the outside temperature (temp) is hot enough to require a Koozie
2. next assess whether it is a weekday and whether it is later than 5:00pm

Here's what I have so far:

```
import datetime
from time import gmtime, strftime

def koozie_decider(temp):

     if datetime.datetime.today().weekday() > 0 and datetime.datetime.today().weekday() < 5:
         if int(strftime("%H", gmtime())) >= 21:
             a = print("Outside of working hours - grab a koozie!")
         else:
             a = print("It's 5 o'clock somewhere - grab a koozie!")
     else:
         a = print("It's the weekend - grab a koozie!")
     if temp >= 72:
         b = print("And it's hot out - you're going to need one ASAP!")
     else:
         b = ""
     return a, b
```

Ideally, I can remove the need for the last "else" statement (while still not returning a string when the temp is below 72). Does anyone know how I could do that?

Also wanted to run this by you all syntactically. The folks at the fair will know a lot more about Python than me, so I want the code to be as efficient as possible.

Are there any low hanging fruit to make this function more "Pythonic"?

Comment: You can just delete that last `else` if you want? i'm a bit confused

Comment: That is not a function, it is just a series of statements.

Comment: Also the whole `a=print(...)` thing looks a bit weird. You could just print whatever, unless is a function called somewhere else and you need to return the print function. But you don't have `def` anywhere...

Comment: `print` doesn't return anything, so assigning to `a` and `b` makes no sense.

Comment: apologies, I added def to make it a function

Comment: If I were to call this function, it would give me two things, `a` and `b`. Can you explain what they are supposed to represent?

Comment: As I said, I'm very new to python, so I'm sure this doesn't make sense, but a and b are simply supposed to represents the strings that I want returned based on the data/time/temp

Comment: will your device have connection to internet at the time of demonstration ? if yes then you should add this feature whether they want to know for certain day and temp ( ask for inputs) or automatically detect day/ time and temp.

Comment: @Ben then you can just return the string without the `print` function

Comment: @Tanmayjain - I'm literally just printing these onto drink koozies, haha, It's just a goofy giveaway to have at the booth. There will be no need to execute the code!

Comment: @Ben ohh, so this function will be literally printed on koozies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so many things in so many different ways. I am surprised this question is still open, anyways like everyone explained in the comments there is no point of doing this `a = print('something...')`

```
>>> t = print()

>>>
>>> a = print('10')
10
>>> a
>>> type(a)
<class 'NoneType'>
>>> def x():
...   a = print('10')
...   return a
...
>>> i = x()
10
>>> type(i)
<class 'NoneType'>
>>>
```

If you still don't exactly understand whats happening here you can ask different question because that means you don't know how print function( python 3.x) works.

```
# pip install weather-api
import datetime
from time import localtime
from weather import Weather, Unit

def koozie_decider(day_idx = localtime().tm_wday, day_hr = localtime().tm_hour, temp = None):

     if temp == None:
         weather = Weather(unit=Unit.FAHRENHEIT)
         location = weather.lookup_by_location('dublin')
         temp = int(location.condition.temp)

     # day_idx = 0-4 mon-fri, | weekend day_idx = 5 and sat day_idx = 6 sun
     if day_idx > 4:
         a = "It's the weekend - grab your favorite Beverage! :D"
     else:
         # if working hrs is between 9( 9) - 5( 17) 24 hr clock
         if 8 < day_hr < 17 :
             a = "Dude it's past 5 somewhere - grab your favorite Beverage, but no Alcohol :( still at work!"
         else:
             a = "Outside of working hours - grab your favorite drink! :D"

     if temp >= 72:
         b = "And it's hot out - grab a koozie, you're going to need one ASAP!"
     else:
         b = "And grab a koozie anyway - coz koozie is lub ;)" 

     return a, b
```

```
a,b = koozie_decider(0,10,78) # monday, 10 something, 78 F
print(a,b,sep = '\n')


Dude it's past 5 somewhere - grab your favorite Beverage, but no Alcohol :( still at work!
And it's hot out - grab a koozie, you're going to need one ASAP!
```

This will look somewhat cool as oppose to giving temperature by yourself. although location still needs to be hard-coded.

```
a,b = koozie_decider()
print(a,b,sep = '\n')

Outside of working hours - grab your favorite drink! :D
And grab a koozie anyway - coz koozie is lub ;)
```

revamped code [koozie_decider](https://pastebin.com/ktsnyk1v).

Comment: cool! Is there a library where I can see the appropriate hard-coded locations? I would hard-code a city that I know there are multiple of in the country

Comment: @Ben you can ask user for city_name and save it to `city_name` variable or you can display list of cities like 1) X 2) Y 3) Z .. and ask user to enter corresponding number. you just need to eventually replace `'dublin'` with the desired city_name `weather.lookup_by_location('dublin')`

Comment: @Ben all you need to do is replace `'dublin'` with `'sydney'` or any other city that you want  so that `weather.lookup_by_location('dublin')` will look like this `weather.lookup_by_location('sydney')`

Comment: even though i don't need to ultimately execute the code, I did want to test it out to make sure it works. for some reason i'm getting the following error on the first "def" line: SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument. any idea how to remediate?

Comment: in what order did you passed in the arguments ? firstly you don't need to pass arguments if you don't want ie you can just do `koozie_decider()`. else do it this way `a,b = koozie_decider(day_idx = 0,day_hr = 18, temp = 78)`

Comment: @Ben read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719368/syntaxerror-non-default-argument-follows-default-argument/39942121) and if you want me to take a look at your code if you have done any modification then paste it [here](https://pastebin.com/) and share the link.