# SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument in python

Tags: python

```
def fn(a=55,b):
    print(a,b)

fn(1,2)
```

This is a python code. After running this error occurred:

```
SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719368/syntaxerror-non-default-argument-follows-default-argument)

Answer (score 0):

In the function definition, default arguments come after non-default arguments. You can read more about [Function Definitions in Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions):

> When one or more parameters have the form parameter `=` expression, the
>   function is said to have *default parameter values*. For a parameter
>   with a default value, the corresponding argument may be omitted from a
>   call, in which case the parameter’s default value is substituted. If a
>   parameter has a default value, all following parameters up until the
>   `*` must also have a default value — this is a syntactic restriction
>   that is not expressed by the grammar.

---

In your case, `b` (non-default) must be defined prior to `a=55` (default).

```
def fn(b, a=55):
    print(a, b)

fn(1, 2)
```