# Currently the function is supposed to take 1 required parameter, and 2 option.... How to fix?

Tags: python, keyword

Currently the function is supposed to take 1 required parameter, and 2 optional parameters, however the code doesn’t work. Fix the code so that it passes the test. This should only require changing one line of code.

```
def waste(var = "Water", mar, marble = "type"):
    final_string = var + " " + marble + " " + mar
    return final_string
```

SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument on line 2
I changed a lot of time fixing it but no result
Thanks!

Comment: Required parameters have to be before optional parameters.

Comment: The error text tells you what is wrong. Default arguments have to be after non-default arguments. The idea is, if you write `waste("xyz")`, then `"xyz"` should be the value of the one argument which is required, so `mar` has to be the first argument.

Comment: duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719368/syntaxerror-non-default-argument-follows-default-argument/39942121

Answer (score 7):

You must have positional arguments first, then named arguments in the function signature in order for the function to work:

```
def waste(mar, var="Water", marble="type"):
    final_string = var + " " + marble + " " + mar
    return final_string
```

You can simplify the function a bit, by returning a f-string (requires Python version >= 3.6):

```
def waste(mar, var="Water", marble="type"):
    return f"{var} {marble} {mar}"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: That is my pleasure. If you found this answer helpful, please consider to mark it as the correct answer. I updated it to show a simpler approach with Python f-strings.