# How does a (python) function process arguments?

Tags: python, function, syntax-error, nameerror

I am wondering how a function is processed in a certain language due to the two errors caused by the following two functions in Python.

```
def fun(a=[0], b: int):
    pass
```

The error reads that `SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument`.

```
# to show that this function is not trivial    
def fun(a:list=[0], b=len(a)):
    pass
```

Araises the error: `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`

The first example shows obviously that `a` is processed before `b`, that is the compiler should know `a` when it encounters `b`, but it seems that the compiler doesn't as shown in the second example.

When(or how) is a parameter defined in a function? Or how can I know what's going on under the hood? I mean the related part of the compiler code, may be implemented in context-free grammar.

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719368/syntaxerror-non-default-argument-follows-default-argument

Answer (score 3):

The *parameter* `a` is a local variable that doesn't actually get defined until the function is *run*; it's not available as a default argument value for `b`. Such a value needs to exist when the function is *defined*.

Answer (score 2):

> The first example shows obviously that `a` is processed before `b`

Not really, at least not in the full meaning of "processed".

The "compiler"/"pre-processor" (non of these terms really apply to Python, but let's let them) can easily check if you use `=` with an argument before another argument which does not have it by just building the AST tree, without "executing" the actual code.

So, `fun(a=0, b)` is wrong **on the language syntax level** (hence the `SyntaxError`). It is detected before the code is even executed, and its presence stops the parsing and the "compilation" of the code.

`fun(a=0, b=a)` is **logically** wrong. The syntax checking mechanism can't/won't detect it. It is only detected by the interpreter when it is trying to execute the code.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> def fun(a=0, b):
> ```

Here you have a default value for `a`, but none for `b`. That means you must provide a value for `b` when calling the function, but not for `a`. However, when you call it like so:

```
fun(42)
```

Which argument will receive the value? `b`, since `a` already has one?

That syntax just raises all sorts of questions, hence you must list all parameters with a default value ***last***. That is the reason for that error.

> ```
> def fun(a=0, b=a):
> ```

Here you're trying to assign the value of a variable `a` as the default value for `b`. That is fine in general:

```
bar = 'baz'

def fun(foo=bar): ...
```

The default value is evaluated once at function declaration time. The `a` in `b=a` does in no way refer to the `a` in `a=0` from the same function declaration. It's looking for a *variable* `a` in scope, which it doesn't find.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `It's looking for a variable a in scope, which it doesn't find.` but why?

Comment: In the first part of your answer about `def fun(a=0, b)` you do explain why we cannot do like that but that is not my question. I know we cannot write that way.

Comment: Perhaps this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1133013/476

Answer (score 0):

Arguments are processed in the order they appear, but if you are going to set a default parameter for any argument then they need to come at the end. Proper syntax would be `def (b, a=0)`. In this case `b` is a required argument, and `a` is optional which defaults to 0 if nothing is passed.