# Python Runtime error (SyntaxErrorException): default value must be specified here

Tags: python, syntax-error, default-value

I have the following code

```
class PV_gen(object):

def __init__(self,_name,surfacename_,performance_type = "PhotovoltaicPerformance:Simple",performance_name,_integrationmode,No_parallel,No_series):

    self.name = _name
    self.surfacename = surfacename_
    self.performancetype = performance_type
    self.performancename =  performance_name
    self.integrationmode = _integrationmode
    self.NOparallel = No_parallel
    self.NOseries = No_series

    self.PV_performance()

def PV_performance(self,_namenamePVperform = "test",SA_solarcells = 0.5 ,cell_efficiencyinputmode = "Fixed",cell_n = 0.12, schedule_ = "always on"):

    self.name = _namenamePVperform
    self.surfaceareacells = SA_solarcells
    self.cellefficiencyinputmode = cell_efficiencyinputmode
    self.efficiency = cell_n
    self.schedule = schedule_
```

Whenever I try to specify a default value in the **init** I am getting a runtime error like so

Runtime error (SyntaxErrorException): default value must be specified here
File "", line 5
        def **init**(self,*name,surfacename*,performance_type = "PhotovoltaicPerformance:Simple",performance_name,_integrationmode,No_parallel,No_series):

SyntaxError: default value must be specified here

I just cannot work out what is going wrong here I want to specify that performance_type has a default value of the string "PhotovoltaicPerformance:Simple". Could someone please give me some pointers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `default argument` must `follow non-default argument`. So the parameter  `performance_type` must be declared at the end.

```
def __init__(self,_name,surfacename_,performance_type = "PhotovoYou ltaicPerformance:Simple",performance_name,_integrationmode,No_parallel,No_series):
```

Should be in following form:

```
def __init__(self,_name,surfacename_,performance_name,_integrationmode,No_parallel,No_series,performance_type = "PhotovoltaicPerformance:Simple"):
```

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932825/why-non-default-arguments-cant-follows-default-argument).

Answer (score 0):

Required parameters must be listed before parameters with defaults.   Move the parameter with a default to the end of the parameter list.