# Learning recursion, error message(non-default argument follows default argument) python

Tags: python, list, recursion

Trying to practice learning recursion. The program is designed to go through the list and print out the location of the chosen letter. I also don't understand what this error message means:(non-default argument follows default argument). Not really understanding why there is an error or how to fix it. Any help always appreciated, thanks.

```
def get_position(pos = 0,List,letter = 'o'):

    if pos < 0:
        pos = 0
    if pos == len(List):
        return None

    if List[pos] is letter:
        return pos
    else:
        return get_position(pos +1,List,letter)


print('position: ',get_position(0,'hello','o'))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why non-default arguments can't follows default argument?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932825/why-non-default-arguments-cant-follows-default-argument)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is on this line:

```
get_position(pos = 0,List,letter = 'o')
```

Notice that you give the `List` argument, a non-default argument, after default argument `pos = 0`. This is not allowed. Try reordering your arguments:

```
get_position(List, pos = 0,letter = 'o')
```

To understand why this is not allowed, think about this: how would you call `get_position` and pass in the *second* argument without passing in the *first* argument? You can think of some ways a language could support this, such as allowing calls like `get_position( , myList)`, but to my knowledge there is no language that does.

Comment: ok, i get it. Something else i tried and worked is change the first argument to simply      (pos)

Comment: Yes, because that makes `pos` no longer a default argument. However, now you have to specify `pos` whenever you call the function, which may or may not be the behavior you desire.