# Python3 abstract class multiple inheritance with abc throws error

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I want to know if it is possible to inherit a class and metaclass=ABCMeta

I tried code like below. However, it throws an error.

> SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Here are my classes. The base class will have some shared functions (with implementation) and class variables. Then, UserBase will not have any implementation. Lastly, office user will inherit UserBase.

It might go like this.

```
Base -> UserBase -> OfficeUser
Base -> UserBase -> OnSiteUser
Base -> UsUserBase -> OnSiteUser
Base -> UsUserBase -> OnSiteUser




class Base():
    def __init__(self):
        print('test')

    def shared_function_with_implementation():
        print('shared function')

# This class will not have any implementation
class UserBase(metaclass=ABCMeta, Base):

    def __init__(self):
        print('test')
        super().__init__()

    @abstractmethod
    def print_name():
        pass

class OfficeUser(UserBase):
    def __init__(self):
        print('OfficeUser')
        super().__init__()

    def print_name():
        # implementation
```

Comment: class UserBase(Base, metaclass=ABCMeta):

keyword arguments can't be front of positional argument. https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#argument

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932825/why-non-default-arguments-cant-follows-default-argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [class definition statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls) follows the known rules from function calls on how the arguments are passed:

```
classdef    ::=  [decorators] "class" classname [inheritance] ":" suite
inheritance ::=  "(" [argument_list] ")"
classname   ::=  identifier
```

where `argument_list` is defined in [the section on Calls](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-argument_list).

You'll need to provide any keyword arguments *after* the positional ones.

In this case, the `metaclass` kwarg should be provided after the base class arg:

```
class UserBase(Base, metaclass=ABCMeta)
```

Comment: I tried that one first and switched after .. but it works for the demo code .. omg. I will try again with actual code. Thanks !