# How do I define an optional argument in function before an un-optional argument?

Tags: python, class, arguments, default

I am working on a 1-Dimensional Segment Class. Every segment is defined by 2 points; the left boundary and the right boundary.

I want the left boundary to be optional (defaults to 0). To do that I would define the `init` function of my class as `def __init__(self, right, left = 0)`.
However, I would like segments to be defined given the left argument first;
for example: `Seg = Segment(1,5)`. Python wouldn't let me define the function as `__init__(self, left = 0, right)`, so what would be an optimal solution for this problem?

Comment: Use `*args` and figure out what the arguments should mean based on `len(args)`

Comment: this provides more info as to why python does not allow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932825/why-non-default-arguments-cant-follows-default-argument

Answer (score 0):

```
def my_func(*args):
        if len(args) == 0:
                print 'missing mandatory param'
        elif len(args) == 1:
                left = 0
                right = args[0]
        elif len(args) == 2:
                left = args[0]
                right = args[1]
        else:   
                print 'wrong number of params provided'

        print 'left is {}'.format(left)
        print 'right is {}'.format(right)
```

when left and right are provided, it'll take the left param as value for `left`

```
my_func(1,2)
left is 1
right is 2
```

when only right is provided, it defaults left to a default value

```
my_func(3)
left is 0
right is 3
```