# Syntax Error: positional argument follows keyword argument:

Tags: python

so here is my code:

```
    def is_valid_move(board, column):
        '''Returns True if and only if there is an open cell in column'''
        for i in board[col]:
            if i == 1 or i == 2:
                return False
            else:
                return True
```

and then I'm trying to test my function using:

```
    print(is_valid_move(board = [[2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
                                 [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
                                 [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1], 
                                 [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1], 
                                 [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1], 
                                 [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1]], 
                        2))
```

I've never gotten this error before so i'm a bit confused on how to actually fix this, or what this even means.

Comment: why are you calling with is_valid_move(board = ***) ? Can you assign board variable with value and pass board variable to function ?

Comment: Remove `board =`.

Comment: or change `2` to `column=2`. i.e. make them both keyword arguments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't non-default arguments follow default arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932825/why-cant-non-default-arguments-follow-default-arguments)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are two types of arguments: positional and keyword.

If we have the function:

```
def f(a, b):
    return a + b
```

Then we can call it with positional arguments:

```
f(4, 4)
# 8
```

Or keyword arguments:

```
f(a=4, b=4)
# 8
```

But not both in the order keyword --> positional, which is what you're doing:

```
f(a=4, 4)
# SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
f(4, b=4)
# 8
```

There's a reason why this is so. Again, imagine we have a similar function:

```
def f(a, b, *args):
    return a + b + sum(args)
```

How would we know when calling this function what argument is `a`, what argument is `b`, and what is for `args`?

Answer (score 0):

Keyword argument should follow non-keyword arguments in function invocation.
In your case, you should assign board to a variable and pass this variable to function.

```
board = [[2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1]]
print(is_valid_move(board, 2))
```

Comment: Maybe call the local variable `b` or something, to make it explicit that the variable's *name* is unimportant.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, taken from the early comment

> Remove board =

Thus, you can just drop the "board =" and pass the value directly, with all parameters as positional arguments:

```
is_valid_move(
    [[2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
    [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1], 
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1], 
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1], 
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1]],
    
    2
)
```

Or use keyword + positional arguments for all parameters:

```
is_valid_move(board=[[2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1]], 
              column=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had keyword arguments (which had a lot longer names in production) and I accidentally had an extra equals sign:

Or keyword arguments:

```
f(a=4, b==4)
# 8
```