# An intuitive way to understand positional argument should not follow keyword argument

Tags: python, parameter-passing

if you write the code like:

```
def test(x,y,z):
    return x+y

test(y=10,5,8)
```

It would raise the error:

```
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

So it seems this is  the rule that everyone knows ,however, I haven't found the clear and intuitive explanations about this.

What I think is that y is keyword argument,and then follow the order of arguments ,so x would be 5 and z would be 8.

I wonder the reason why we can't do this,is there ant part that would confuse the compiler?

If an example can be showed,it would be really awesome!

Comment: Perhaps you can look at the [discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932825/why-cant-non-default-arguments-follow-default-arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Python compiler limitation to reduce the need for under-the-hood dictionary lookups. There's not actually an ambiguous case or anything they're avoiding.

You can see where the dict lookup would need to happen though:

```
def test(x, y):
    return x + y

test(y=10, 5)
```

Follow the compiler from top-left to bottom-right...

With kwargs allowed to come before positional args:

1. Read `y=10`
2. Put into `kwargs` dict (expensive).
3. Read `5`.
4. Check if first positional arg name `x` is in `kwargs` dict (expensive).
5. Put into `x` positional arg.

Without wkargs allowed before positional args:

1. Read `y=10`
2. Put into `kwargs` dict (expensive).
3. Read `5`.
4. Throw and error (easy?)

Now consider the case where plain arguments are used, which (can be) fast.

```
def test(x, y):
    return x + y

test(10, 5)
```

Keywords first allowed:

1. Read `10`.
2. Check `kwarg` dict for `x` (expensive).
3. Put in `x` arg.
4. Read `5`.
5. Check `kwarg` dict for `y` (expensive).
6. Put in `y` arg.

Args must be first:

1. Read `10`.
2. Put in `x` arg.
3. Read `5`.
4. Put in `y` arg.

This difference isn't compiled out in Python, because the byte-code still allows for dynamic function calls. Python devs decided to forbid keyword-first syntax to make the language a little faster at run time.

PS: There is also an argument that putting keywords before positional args is harder to read, but I'll leave aesthetic judgements to the critics. I think it looks fine.