# How to give func_args to feval in oct2py? (Windows)

Tags: python, octave

I'm new on programming and is hard to read documentation. I need to add arguments to my octave script from Python. In the documentation says this about feval:

```
Parameters
func_path: str
Name of function to run or a path to an m-file.
func_args: object, optional
Args to send to the function
```

I'm using PyCharm 2018.1.4 (Community Edition) Windows 10 10.0 and I have already add the Environment Variable OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE=C:\Octave\Octave-5.1.0.0\mingw64\bin\octave-cli.exe

For functions without parameters I have no problems because is an optional parameter.

The code in Python that I'm using and has worked is:

```py
from oct2py import Oct2Py
oc = Oct2Py()
z = oc.feval(func_path='C:/Users/Me/PycharmProjects/T1/hip.m')
print(z)
```

Because I use an octave code that doesn't need optional arguments:

```matlab
function r = hip()
r = sqrt(4^2+2^2);
end
```

This code returns the value of 'r' in Python. But now I need to give two arguments like this:

```matlab
function r = hip(x,y)
r = sqrt(x^2+y^2);
end
```

If someone can give me an example using 'func_args'. The error message is usually this:

```
oct2py.utils.Oct2PyError: Octave evaluation error:
error: 'x' undefined near line 2 column 10
error: called from:
hip at line 2, column 3
```

EDIT: The complete error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/LuisE/PycharmProjects/T1/oct2py_v1.py", line 4, in <module>
    z = oc.feval(func_path='C:/Users/Me/PycharmProjects/T1/hip.m')
  File "C:\Users\Me\PycharmProjects\T1\T2\lib\site-packages\oct2py\core.py", line 379, in feval
    store_as=store_as, plot_dir=plot_dir)
  File "C:\Users\Me\PycharmProjects\T1\T2\lib\site-packages\oct2py\core.py", line 579, in _feval
    raise Oct2PyError(msg)
oct2py.utils.Oct2PyError: Octave evaluation error:
error: 'x' undefined near line 2 column 10
error: called from:
    hipotenusa at line 2, column 3
```

Comment: Can you show the python code which gives the error message ?

Comment: Refer to this https://blink1073.github.io/oct2py/source/info.html#using-m-files

Comment: I tried x=2, y=4 and oc.feval(func_path='C:/Users/Me/PycharmProjects/T1/hip.m',x,y) but it returns this: File "C:/Users/LuisE/PycharmProjects/T1/oct2py_v1.py", line 6
    z = oc.feval(func_path='C:/Users/Me/PycharmProjects/T1/hip.m', x, y)
                                                                            ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Comment: Try this ```oc.feval('C:/Users/Me/PycharmProjects/T1/hip.m',x,y)```

Comment: This was the solution: oc.feval('C:/Users/Me/PycharmProjects/T1/hip.m',x,y). But I don't understand why it worked at first time adding 'func_path'.

Comment: have a look here for the reason : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932825/why-cant-non-default-arguments-follow-default-arguments

Comment: note that `oc.feval` does exactly the same thing that the `feval` function would do in octave. And generally, that's not the way to call functions in octave. You can `cd` to the correct folder in your oct2py instance(i.e. `oc.cd('C:\Users\Me\PycharmProjects\T1')`), and then run the function directly (e.g. `oc.hip(x,y)`)

Comment: also, if you don't need more than one octave session, you can import `octave` instead, which is a singleton instance of the Oct2Py class provided for convenience (eg. `from oct2py import octave as oc` )