# Python named vs unnamed argments

Tags: arguments, named

suppose we have this one-line python function here 
def fun (a, b=0):
    return a+b

this statement here works fine
c = fun(10, b=22)

but this one here does not

d = fun(a=1, 0)

what am I missing here?

Comment: The error message should be quite clear on why it's not ok...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't non-default arguments follow default arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932825/why-cant-non-default-arguments-follow-default-arguments)

Comment: @Sweeper error message says SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg