# PYTHON3: non-default argument follows default argument

Tags: python-3.x, function, variables

Actually i am a newbie to the programming world and i have defined a very simple function that will just add three numbers.

Here's the code:

```
 def sum(a=2,b,c):
     print(a+b+c)

 sum(b=1,c=3)
```

But it just returns me an error: SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument

It would be great help if someone could explain this error. Thanks.

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932825/why-cant-non-default-arguments-follow-default-arguments

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have default arguments (`a=2`) before positional arguments (`b`, `c`). Fix this by putting `a` at the back of the signature (or change `c` to be the default argument).

```
def sum(a, b, c=2):
```

This is because it can make calls very confusing. For instance, let's say you have this signature:

```
def sum(a, b=2, c, d=4):
```

What happens when the user calls

```
sum(1, 2, 3)
```

Do they mean `sum(a=1, b=2, c=3)`, or `sum(a=1, c=2, d=3)`?

Comment: But i have set the values for b and c respectively. Then why the interpreter is getting confused??

Comment: The interpreter is yelling about the function signature, not about how you are calling it. It's not designed to conditionally complain about the signature only if the calls are ambiguous.