# Passing variable to nn.Conv2d arguments within a class init definition python

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, pytorch, conv-neural-network

So I want to pass some new variables such as kernel_size when I initiate a new object. Let's say `net=Net10(5,2,4,3,1,1)`. so that I get an object of this class with the parameters I want not something always constant, cos otherwise I will have to define lots of classes. Now, I want to pass `kernel_size` within the `self.Conv2d`, and I get a syntax error: `positional argument follows keyword argument`
Does anyone know how to fix this? Should I change it all to functions instead of classes?

```
    class Net10(nn.Module):   
    def __init__ (self, kernel_size, stride, pooling, num_classes, neurons, ActFunn, *args):
        super(Net10, self).__init__()
        self.kernel = kernel_size
        self.stride = stride
        self.pooling = pooling
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.neurons = neurons
        self.Actfun = ActFunn   
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=32, kernel, padding=2, stride=1)                 
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(pooling, pooling)
        self.fcinput= round (28 / pooling)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't non-default arguments follow default arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932825/why-cant-non-default-arguments-follow-default-arguments)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=32, kernel_size=self.kernel, padding=2, stride=1)
```

In more details: python functions (e.g., `__init__` of the conv layer) can have input arguments is two "flavors": *positional* arguments: that is associating an input argument to a function variable according to its *position* in the argument list.
The other "flavor" is *keyword* argument: argument that is given with its keyword, e.g., `in_channels=1` etc.

As a rule python does not allow wild mixing of positional and keyword arguments.
You can have positional arguments followed by keyword argument, but you cannot have a positional argument once you started declaring keyword arguments.

```py
self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1,   # keyword argument
   out_channels=32,   # keyword argument
   kernel,   # positional argument (no "keyword" defining this argument)
   padding=2,  # keyword
   stride=1)   # keyword
```

Comment: I did so. Now I get a NameError: name 'kernel' is not defined

Comment: @SabaDaftari it's`kernel_size=kernel`

Comment: There is no `kernel` variable, only `self.kernel` and `kernel_size`, so it would be either `kernel_size=self.kernel` or `kernel_size=kernel_size`.