# DJANGO - Error with complex AND, OR condition in 1 FILTER, but works with many FILTERS ? Why?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I had this query which I did quite nice

```py
query = LeadtimeConfig.objects.filter(last_mile__isnull = True,  
                                      Q(origin = _origin_area) | Q(origin__isnull = True),  
                                      Q(destination =_destination_area) | Q(destination__isnull=True),  
                                      Q(delivery_type = _delivery_type) | Q(delivery_type__isnull = True) | Q(delivery_type = '') )
```

However, I keep receiving this error

```
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

But works when I did this:

```
query = LeadtimeConfig.objects.filter(last_mile__isnull = True)
                              .filter(Q(origin = _origin_area) | Q(origin__isnull = True))
                              .filter(Q(destination =_destination_area) | Q(destination__isnull=True))
                              .filter(Q(delivery_type = _delivery_type) | Q(delivery_type__isnull = True) | Q(delivery_type = ''))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't non-default arguments follow default arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932825/why-cant-non-default-arguments-follow-default-arguments)

Answer (score 1):

You need the Q element to be the first parameter, like so:

```py
query = LeadtimeConfig.objects.filter(Q(origin = _origin_area)|Q(origin__isnull = True), Q(destination =_destination_area)|Q(destination__isnull=True), Q(delivery_type = _delivery_type) | Q(delivery_type__isnull = True) | Q(delivery_type = ''), last_mile__isnull = True)
```

**or** you can put the positional parameter `last_mile__isnull` with a Q lookup also, like so:

```py
query = LeadtimeConfig.objects.filter(Q(last_mile__isnull = True), Q(origin = _origin_area)|Q(origin__isnull = True), Q(destination =_destination_area)|Q(destination__isnull=True), Q(delivery_type = _delivery_type) | Q(delivery_type__isnull = True) | Q(delivery_type = ''))
```

If you refer to the [Django[Docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) you'll see an example like yours at the bottom of the section which shows as invalid.

Comment: Well, thanks. I thought `Q` only used for the case of  `OR` only

Comment: @ChauLoi no problem, hope this helps.