# Project for programming class. I keep receiving the same error

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface

I am new to python and I am trying to create an application in Gui Python. The goal is to create a sign up/ register page. Then, four possibilities should open to the user

- Claculator
- File write
- BMI calculator
- Exit

The code worked perfectly until I tried to add the first page with the register or sign up button. Now I kee receiving this error:
**"positional argument follows keyword argument"**
However, I can't find where is the mistake. I would really appreciate if someone could help me!!!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import functions




class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.title("Healtheat")
        self.switch(Entering)
        self.geometry('350x350')
        self.config(bg = "black")

    def switch(self, frame_class):
        """Destroys current frame and replaces it with a chosen by the user"""
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()

class Entering(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.config(bg = "black")

        global main_screen
        main_screen.title("Heyyy :)")
        Label(text="Select Your Choice", bg="lightseagreen", width="300", height="2", font=("Calibri", 13)).pack()
        Label(text="").pack()
        Button(text="Login", height="2", width="30", command = lambda: master.switch(Login)).pack()
        Label(text="").pack()
        Button(text="Register", height="2", width="30", command = lambda: master.switch(Register)).pack()


class Register(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.config(bg = "black")

    def register():
        global register_screen
        register_screen = Toplevel(main_screen)
        register_screen.title("Join us our team")
        register_screen.geometry("350x350")

        global username
        global password
        global img
        global username_entry
        global password_entry

        username = StringVar()
        password = StringVar()


        Label(register_screen, text="Please enter details below", bg="red").pack()
        Label(register_screen, text="").pack()

        username_lable = Label(register_screen, text="Username * ")
        username_lable.pack()
        username_entry = Entry(register_screen, textvariable=username)
        username_entry.pack()

        password_lable = Label(register_screen, text="Password * ")
        password_lable.pack()
        password_entry = Entry(register_screen, textvariable=password, show='*')
        password_entry.pack()

        Label(register_screen, text="").pack()
        Button(register_screen, text="Register", width=10, height=1, bg="lightseagreen", lambda: master.switch(Login)).pack()

class Login(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.config(bg = "black")

    def login(self):
        global login
        login_screen = Toplevel(main_screen)
        login_screen.title("Welcome back!")
        login_screen.geometry("350x350")
        Label(login_screen, text="Please enter details below to login").pack()
        Label(login_screen, text="").pack()

        global username_verify
        global password_verify

        self.username_verify = StringVar()
        self.password_verify = StringVar()

        global username_login_entry
        global password_login_entry

        Label(login_screen, text="Username * ").pack()
        username_login_entry = Entry(login_screen, textvariable=username_verify)
        username_login_entry.pack()
        Label(login_screen, text="").pack()
        Label(login_screen, text="Password * ").pack()
        password_login_entry = Entry(login_screen, textvariable=password_verify, show='*')
        password_login_entry.pack()
        Label(login_screen, text="").pack()
        Button(login_screen, text="Login", width=10, height=1, command=login_verify).pack()

    def login_verify(self):
        self.username1 = username_verify.get()
        self.password1 = password_verify.get()
        username_login_entry.delete(0, END)
        password_login_entry.delete(0, END)

        list_of_files = os.listdir()
        if username1 in list_of_files:
            file1 = open(username1, "r")
            verify = file1.read().splitlines()
            if password1 in verify:
                login_sucess()

            else:
                password_not_recognised()

        else:
            user_not_found()

    def login_sucess(self):
        global login_success_screen
        login_success_screen = Toplevel(login_screen)
        login_success_screen.title("Success")
        login_success_screen.geometry("150x100")
        Label(login_success_screen, text="Login Success").pack()
        Button(login_success_screen, text="OK", lambda: master.switch(Menu)).pack()

    def password_not_recognised(self):
        global password_not_recog_screen
        password_not_recog_screen = Toplevel(login_screen)
        password_not_recog_screen.title("Success")
        password_not_recog_screen.geometry("150x100")
        Label(password_not_recog_screen, text="Invalid Password ").pack()
        Button(password_not_recog_screen, text="OK", command=delete_password_not_recognised).pack()

    def user_not_found(self):
        global user_not_found_screen
        user_not_found_screen = Toplevel(login_screen)
        user_not_found_screen.title("Success")
        user_not_found_screen.geometry("150x100")
        Label(user_not_found_screen, text="User Not Found").pack()
        Button(user_not_found_screen, text="OK", command=delete_user_not_found_screen).pack()


    def delete_login_success(self):
        login_success_screen.destroy(self)

    def delete_password_not_recognised(self):
        password_not_recog_screen.destroy(self)

    def delete_user_not_found_screen(self):
        user_not_found_screen.destroy(self)



class Menu(Frame):
    """Main menu"""
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.config(bg = "black")

        """Frame widgets"""
        label = Label(self, text = "Project Notes Presents Nutrition Calculator!\n Choose an option."\
                      , bg = "black", fg = "white")
        label.pack()
        button = Button(self, text = "Calculator", width = 20, command = lambda: master.switch(Calculator))
        button.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10)
        button2 = Button(self, text = "Add a product", width = 20, command = lambda: master.switch(File_Write))
        button2.pack()
        button3 = Button(self, text = "BMI Calculator", width = 20, command = lambda: master.switch(BMI))
        button3.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10)
        button4 = Button(self, text = "Exit", width = 20, command = self.close)
        button4.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10)


    def close(self):
        """Close the app"""
        self.destroy()
        exit()


class Calculator(Frame):
    """Writing nutritional values of the user defined food"""
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.config(bg = "black")

        def on_click():
            """Checking data and writing the results"""
            product = entryProduct.get()
            gram = entryGram.get()
            output.delete(0.0, END)

            Error = False
            try:
                gram = int(entryGram.get())
            except:
                Error = True
            try:
                x = int(product)
                Error = True
            except:
                pass
            if Error == True:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please enter correct data!")
            else:
                functions.file_open()
                output.insert(END, functions.result(product, gram))

        """Frame widgets"""
        label = Label(self, text ="Enter a product that you ate.", bg = "black", fg = "white")
        label.pack()
        # user input, product
        label2 = Label(self, text = "Name: ", bg = "black", fg = "white")
        label2.pack()
        entryProduct = Entry(self, width = 20, bg = "white")
        entryProduct.pack()
        # user input, amount
        label3 = Label(self, text = "Amount: ", bg = "black", fg = "white")
        label3.pack()
        entryGram = Entry(self, width = 20, bg = "white")
        entryGram.pack()
        # submit
        submit = Button(self, text = "Submit", width = 8, command = on_click)
        submit.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10)
        # output
        label4 = Label(self, text = "These are the nutrition values:", bg = "black", fg = "white")
        label4.pack()
        output = Text(self, width = 20, height = 6, wrap = WORD, bg = "white")
        output.pack()
        #going back to menu
        self.button = Button(self, text = "Back", width = 8, command = lambda: master.switch(Menu))
        self.button.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10)


class File_Write(Frame):
    """User can add new new products and their values"""
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.config(bg = "black")

        def validate():
            """Checks is the user inputs correct data"""
            def write(name, kcal, protein, carb, fat):
                """Writes to file"""
                file = open("../../Downloads/PN-NutritionalCalculator/Products.txt", "a")
                productValue = "%s,%s:%s:%s:%s" % (name, kcal, protein, carb, fat)
                file.write("\n" + productValue)
                file.close()
                #Emptying inputs
                nameEntry.delete(0, END)
                kcalEntry.delete(0, END)
                proteinEntry.delete(0, END)
                carbEntry.delete(0, END)
                fatEntry.delete(0, END)

            error = False
            # checking if kcal, protein, carb and fat are integers and productName is a string
            try:
                name = int(nameEntry.get())
                error = True
            except:
                 name = nameEntry.get()
            try:
                kcal = int(kcalEntry.get())
                protein = int(proteinEntry.get())
                carb = int(carbEntry.get())
                fat = int(fatEntry.get())
            except:
                error = True
            if error == True:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please enter correct data!")
            else:
                #writing to a file
                write(name, kcal, protein, carb, fat)

        """Frame widgets"""
        label = Label(self, text ="Enter the product name and its nutritional "\
                "values per 100 gram", bg = "black", fg = "white")
        label.pack()
        label1 = Label(self, text = "Name:", bg = "black", fg = "white")
        label1.pack()
        nameEntry = Entry(self, width = 20, bg = "white")
        nameEntry.pack()

        label2 = Label(self, text = "Calories:", bg = "black", fg = "white")
        label2.pack()
        kcalEntry = Entry(self, width = 20, bg = "white")
        kcalEntry.pack()

        label3 = Label(self, text = "Protein:", bg = "black", fg = "white")
        label3.pack()
        proteinEntry = Entry(self, width = 20, bg = "white")
        proteinEntry.pack()

        label4 = Label(self, text = "Carbs:", bg = "black", fg = "white")
        label4.pack()
        carbEntry = Entry(self, width = 20, bg = "white")
        carbEntry.pack()

        label5 = Label(self, text = "Fat:", bg = "black", fg = "white")
        label5.pack()
        fatEntry = Entry(self, width = 20, bg = "white")
        fatEntry.pack()

        submit = Button(self, text = "Submit", width = 8, command = validate)
        submit.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10)

        button3 = Button(self, text = "Back", width = 20, command = lambda: master.switch(Menu))
        button3.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10)

class BMI(Frame):
    """Writing nutritional values of the user defined food"""
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.config(bg = "black")

        def calculate_bmi(a=""):
            print(a)
            try:
                height = entryheight.get()
                weight = entryweight.get()
                height = float(height) / 100.0
                bmi = float(weight) / (height ** 2)
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                messagebox.showinfo("Result", "Please enter positive height!!")
            except ValueError:
                messagebox.showinfo("Result", "Please enter valid data!")
            else:
                if bmi <= 15.0:
                    res = "Your BMI is " + str(bmi) + "\nRemarks: Very severely underweight!!"
                    messagebox.showinfo("Result", res)
                elif 15.0 < bmi <= 16.0:
                    res = "Your BMI is " + str(bmi) + "\nRemarks: Severely underweight!"
                    messagebox.showinfo("Result", res)
                elif 16.0 < bmi < 18.5:
                    res = "Your BMI is " + str(bmi) + "\nRemarks: Underweight!"
                    messagebox.showinfo("Result", res)
                elif 18.5 <= bmi <= 25.0:
                    res = "Your BMI is " + str(bmi) + "\nRemarks: Normal."
                    messagebox.showinfo("Result", res)
                elif 25.0 < bmi <= 30:
                    res = "Your BMI is " + str(bmi) + "\nRemarks: Overweight."
                    messagebox.showinfo("Result", res)
                elif 30.0 < bmi <= 35.0:
                    res = "Your BMI is " + str(bmi) + "\nRemarks: Moderately obese!"
                    messagebox.showinfo("Result", res)
                elif 35.0 < bmi <= 40.0:
                    res = "Your BMI is " + str(bmi) + "\nRemarks: Severely obese!"
                    messagebox.showinfo("Result", res)
                else:
                    res = "Your BMI is " + str(bmi) + "\nRemarks: Super obese!!"
                    messagebox.showinfo("Result", res)


        """Frame widgets"""
        label = Label(self, text="Welcome to your BMI Calculator", bg="black", fg="white")
        label.pack()
        # user input, product
        label2 = Label(self, text="Weight (kg)", bg="black", fg="white")
        label2.pack()
        entryweight = Entry(self, width=20, bg="white")
        entryweight.pack()
        # user input, amount
        label3 = Label(self, text="Height(cm)", bg="black", fg="white")
        label3.pack()
        entryheight = Entry(self, width=20, bg="white")
        entryheight.pack()
        # submit
        submit = Button(self, text="Submit", width=8, command=calculate_bmi)
        submit.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        # going back to menu
        self.button = Button(self, text="Back", width=8, command=lambda: master.switch(Menu))
        self.button.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your IDE will normally tell you where in the code the error is.  What error do you get exactly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't non-default arguments follow default arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932825/why-cant-non-default-arguments-follow-default-arguments)

Comment: Could you try to create a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? By doing that you will probably solve the issue by yourself.

Comment: Can you post the exception?  You are calling a method and passing in a positional argument AFTER you've passed in a keyword argument. i.e. `method(first, second=keyword, third)` - this needs to be `method(first, third, second=keyword)`

Comment: Please make sure to construct a [mre]. Note that all three of those words are important: it should be an *example* only, you should not post your entire actual code, rather you should create a simplified example that demonstrates your problem. Also, it should be *minimal*, i.e. it should not contain anything that is not absolutely required to demonstrate the problem. (Most beginner problems can be demonstrated in less than 5 short simple lines of code.) And it should be *reproducible*, which means that if I copy&paste and run the code, I should see the exact same problem you see.

Comment: You have posted almost 300 lines of code, when I am willing to bet that 4 lines would suffice to reproduce the problem. Also, you have not posted the error message which would tell us exactly where the problem lies since it contains the name of the source file, the line number, as well as the call stack. https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the `register` method in the class `Register` and add `command =` before your lambda expression

```
Button(register_screen, text="Register", width=10, height=1, bg="lightseagreen", command = lambda: master.switch(Login)).pack()
```

Repeat this for all instances where you don't define the keyword `command =`
in your method invocations.

For example, the `login_success()` method in the class `Login` needs it too

```
Button(login_success_screen, text="OK", command = lambda: master.switch(Menu)).pack()
```