# Get parameter list of pymc object

Tags: python, function, object, pymc

I am trying to write a generic function which accepts a user-defined function, a list of priors(apart from other things) and the does something (irrelevant for this question)

for eg  ( ... in the following code-snippets refers to irrelevant information )

```
generic_func(..., pred, [pymc.Uniform("a", 0, 5), pymc.Unform("b", 0, 1)], ...)
```

where user_fn is defined as

```
def pred(...,a, b, ...) : ...
```

I  need to define the generic_func, I do it as follows :

```
def generic_func(..., user_fn, fittable_prior_list, optional_arguments_for_user_fn):
    h = {}
    for params in fittable_prior_list:
         h[params.name] = params
    user_fn(..., **h, ...)
```

I don't want to constrain the user to pass arguments in the same order as user_fn expects, that's why I am using a dictionary. I have assumed that the priors in the list will have same name as that of arguments of user_fn (I will be happy to know if this assumption can be done away with, but I am okay even if this assumption holds)

But I get the following error :

```
AttributeError: 'Uniform' object has no attribute 'name'
```

I went on these links [How can I read a function's signature including default argument values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677185/how-read-method-signature) , also [Getting method parameter names in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218616/getting-method-parameter-names-in-python)

Then I tried

```
tau = pm.Uniform(name = "tau", lower=0, upper=5)
argspec = inspect.getargspec(tau).args
```

and I get the following error

```
TypeError: <pymc.distributions.Uniform 'tau' at 0x9a3210c> is not a Python function
```

**Is there a way I can access the name of these pymc objects ?**

**Though this is not the main question, I will also be happy to know if there is a better way to solve this problem than the one I am using.**

Answer (score 0):

The objects in question store their names in the `__name__` attribute.  They can be accessed like this:

```
import pymc
obj = pymc.Uniform("a", 0, 5)
print obj.__name__
```

Comment: Your answer is being picked up by the low quality filter. Can you add some information at why this code block solves OPs problem?

Comment: Your answer is being picked up by the low quality filter. Can expand on your answer?