# Is it possible to determine the minimum arity and the relevant parameter names of a Python function without calling it?

Tags: python-3.x, reflection

Say I have this function:

```
def destroy_all_the_users(a, b, c, d, e, f=2, *g, **h):
  i = 2
```

It seems I can calculate its minimum arity (the minimum amount of arguments I have to give it) like so:

```
import types

# This doesn't work on some C functions like, say, file.write
def get_minimum_arity(func_alike):
  # This might not be a function but a method
  if type(func_alike) is types.MethodType:
    func_alike = func_alike.im_func
  # This might not be a function but a __call__'able
  if type(func_alike) is not types.FunctionType:
    func_alike = func_alike.__call__

  return func_alike.__code__.co_argcount - len(func_alike.__defaults__)
```

How can I, however, determine the *names* of those 5 arguments? For `destroy_all_the_users`, that would be `('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')`. Attributes that may look promising aren't (for instance, `destroy_all_the_users.__code__.co_varnames` also include `g, h, i`) and I don't necessarily have the source code of the function. The output of `dis.dis(destroy_all_the_users)` seems similarly unhelpful.

<sub>Say for example that I want to check for the `file`ness of an arbitrary class that may not even derive from `file`. All that you really care about is that this arbitrary class has enough of the same methods (say, `write`), which means that *at least* they should accept the same number of parameters (1, but more optional arguments are not a problem) and the same parameter names (...bad example: it seems that `file.write` is special and doesn't allow its mandatory arguments to be passed by keyword)).</sub>

Comment: Bonus points: is it possible for this function to execute both `if` branches?

Comment: duplicate of [How read method signature?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677185/how-read-method-signature)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines of code

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getfullargspec(destroy_all_the_users)
```

gives you this output :

```
FullArgSpec(args=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
            varargs='g',
            varkw='h',
            defaults=(2,),
            kwonlyargs=[],
            kwonlydefaults=None,
            annotations={})
```