# How do I get a function's full name and arguments as string from a list of function objects in Python?

Tags: python, function, introspection

As the title says, I am interested in a list of all functions inside my python module as string. So far I have a list of function objects with their possible arguments.

For example, with NumPy

```
from inspect import getmembers, isfunction
import numpy

functions_list = getmembers(numpy, isfunction)
functions_list = [x[1] for x in functions_list] #functions_list = [str(x[1]).split(' ')[1] for x in functions_list]

functions_list[:4]
```

Output:

```
[<function numpy.__dir__()>,
 <function numpy.__getattr__(attr)>,
 <function numpy.core.function_base.add_newdoc(place, obj, doc, warn_on_python=True)>,
 <function numpy.alen(a)>]
```

If I try list comprehension and parse the function object to a string with str(x) as follows:

```
functions_list = [str(x[1]) for x in functions_list]
```

Output:

```
['<function __dir__ at 0x000001C9D44AF310>',
 '<function __getattr__ at 0x000001C9D40BFD30>',
 '<function add_newdoc at 0x000001C9D42C0C10>',
 '<function alen at 0x000001C9D42610D0>']
```

Same for:

```
str(functions_list)
repr(functions_list)
```

I want something like:

```
['numpy.__dir__()',
 'numpy.__getattr__(attr)',
 'numpy.core.function_base.add_newdoc(place, obj, doc, warn_on_python=True)',
 'numpy.alen(a)']
```

How can I archive this? I know there are a lot of similar questions here, and I look up a few of them, but I couldn't find something that helps me out.

Comment: Is your next question going to be "How to call a function by its string name?" ?

Comment: @DeepSpace3 No I write a document and don't want to write it all down by myself :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it is not perfect, how about using `inspect.signature`?

```py
from inspect import getmembers, isfunction, signature
import numpy

def explain(m):
    try:
        return f"{m[0]}{signature(m[1])}"
    except ValueError:
        return f"{m[0]}(???)" # some functions don't provide a signature

print(*(explain(m) for m in getmembers(numpy, isfunction)), sep='\n')

# __dir__()
# __getattr__(attr)
# add_newdoc(place, obj, doc, warn_on_python=True)
# alen(a)
# all(a, axis=None, out=None, keepdims=<no value>, *, where=<no value>)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a better way to do this, but you could cobble it together yourself from [`f.__module__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#:%7E:text=Writable-,__module__,-The%20name%20of), [`f.__name__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#definition.__name__), and the [function signature](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2677185/4518341).

```
import numpy as np
from inspect import signature
f = np.core.function_base.add_newdoc
print(f'{f.__module__}.{f.__name__}{signature(f)}')
```

Output:

```
numpy.core.function_base.add_newdoc(place, obj, doc, warn_on_python=True)
```

But this doesn't work for functions that don't provide a signature, like `np.where()`. See [j1-lee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70993202/4518341) about that.