# Dynamically get a function from a file based on the files name with parameters

Tags: python

I'm creating a factory class that is able to dynamically build out an object based on a bunch of individual blocks (small functions of code). It takes a JSON object that it traverses through, and based on the key of what is being asked it will dynamically select a function from a file.

The benefit from this approach is that you won't have to update the factory class when adding new functionality, just add a new file with the specific function you're looking to add.

What I'm not sure how to do is dynamically get and populate the list of parameters for a given function, which may vary in length and what type of parameter they are.

For example lets say I have 2 files:

```
file #1: foo.py
def foo(a, b):
   return a + b

file #2 bar.py
def bar(a, b, c):
   return [a, b, c]
```

Both these files exist in a subfolder called blocks to the factory. The factory file should be able to find those files and call the functions with the correct parameters given a name.

```
class Factory():
    a: str
    b: str
    c: str
    factory_directory: str

    __init__(self):
        self.factory_directory = Path().absolute()

    get_block(self, name):
        path = self.factory_directory + '/block/' + name + '.py'
        if os.path.exists(path):
            function = importlib.import_module('path')
        else:
            raise Exception
```

Is there a way to dynamically build out what the parameters are assuming they already exist as properties on the factory class? One idea I had was to create a class for each function, and have that class include information about what parameters it needs but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: I am not fully sure, what exactly you want to achieve and I guess that the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677185/how-can-i-read-a-functions-signature-including-default-argument-values) will be helpful. Please describe in detail what you want to achieve.