# Is there a way to check a function's signature in Python?

Tags: python

I'm looking for a way to check the number of arguments that a given function takes in Python.  The purpose is to achieve a more robust method of patching my classes for tests.  So, I want to do something like this:

```
class MyClass (object):
    def my_function(self, arg1, arg2):
        result = ... # Something complicated
        return result

def patch(object, func_name, replacement_func):
    import new

    orig_func = getattr(object, func_name)
    replacement_func = new.instancemethod(replacement_func, 
                           object, object.__class__)

    # ...
    # Verify that orig_func and replacement_func have the 
    # same signature.  If not, raise an error.
    # ...

    setattr(object, func_name, replacement_func)

my_patched_object = MyClass()
patch(my_patched_object, "my_function", lambda self, arg1: "dummy result")
# The above line should raise an error!
```

Thanks.

Comment: "patching my classes for tests"?  Why aren't you using mock objects?  http://python-mock.sourceforge.net/?

Comment: I'm new to using mocks.  I "grew up" stubbing and patching.  I'm getting practice and figuring out when to use which, but in the mean time, I still have projects to finish, and tests to write :).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use:

```
import inspect
len(inspect.getargspec(foo_func)[0])
```

This won't acknowledge variable-length parameters, like:

```
def foo(a, b, *args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

Comment: Now, it should be `inspect.getfullargspec(foo)[0]` for new Python version.

Answer (score 21):

`inspect.getargspec` is deprecated in Python 3. Consider something like:

```
import inspect
len(inspect.signature(foo).parameters)
```

This *will* include `args` and `kwargs` as one parameter, each.

If you don't want to include `args` and `kwargs`, consider:

```
len(inspect.getfullargspec(foo)[0])
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use [`inspect.getargspec`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec).

Answer (score 2):

The [`inspect`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) module allows you to examine a function's arguments. This has been asked a few times on Stack Overflow; try searching for some of those answers. For example:

[Getting method parameter names in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218616/getting-method-parameter-names-in-python)

Comment: I see.  I did a bit of searching before posting, but I guess I should have use more search terms.  Sorry for the bother.

Comment: No problem. Better to point to you to the other answers, though, than just repeat everything here.

Answer (score 0):

Using the accepted answer you can even construct the entire type like this:

```py
import inspect
from typing import Callable, Any, Type, List

def ftype(func: Callable[[Any], Any]) -> Type[Callable[[Any], Any]]:
    assert callable(func)
    ret = inspect.signature(func).return_annotation
    params = list(inspect.signature(func).parameters.values())
    param_types: List[Type[Any]] = [param.annotation for param in params]
    return Callable[[*param_types], ret]
```

In your code you can then check the type with the `is` keyword like this:

```py
def equal_strings(text1: str, text2: str) -> bool:
    return text1 == text2

# ...

>>> my_fuction is Callable[[str, str], bool] 
True

>>> ftype(equal_strings)
typing.Callable[[str, str], bool]
```

**However** mypy doesn't like any of this, which is probably what lead you here in the first place.

I just thought this piece of magic was interesting

Answer (score 0):

I have written my own small library that solves this problem with less client code, it's called [sigmatch](https://github.com/pomponchik/sigmatch).

Install it:

```
pip install sigmatch
```

And use:

```
from sigmatch import SignatureMatcher

def function(a, b, c=5, *d, **e):
    ...

matcher = SignatureMatcher('.', '.', 'c', '*', '**')
print(matcher.match(function))  # True
```

In this example, the expected parameters of the function are fixed in the `SignatureMatcher` object, and the `match()` method checks the function for compliance with them. That's what the `SignatureMatcher` initialization parameters mean:

- `"."` - corresponds to an ordinary positional arguments without a
  default value.
- `"some_argument_name"` - corresponds to an argument with a default
  value. The content of the string is the name of the argument.
- `"*"` - corresponds to packing multiple positional arguments without
  default values (*args).
- `"**"` - corresponds to packing several named arguments with default
  values (**kwargs).