# Check python function signature without a call

Tags: python, function, signature, typechecking

My program derives a sequence `args` and a mapping `kwargs` from  user input.  I want to check that input, and then forward it to a python function `f` (which is chosen based on user input).  In this case, a function signature mismatch between `f` and `[kw]args` is an *input* error; I must distinguish it from possible *programming* errors within the implementation of `f`, even though they might both raise `TypeError`.

So I want to check the signature before attempting the function call.  Is there a way to do this other than to manually compare `[kw]args` to the result of `inspect.getargspec` (or `.getfullargspec` or `.signature` in later python versions)?

**Related questions:** [Is there a way to check a function's signature in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534852/is-there-a-way-to-check-a-functions-signature-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method using `inspect` is probably the most straightforward way of doing this that exists - it's not something one would normally expect to be doing in Python.

(Typically, allowing end users to call arbitrary functions with arbitrary inputs is not what a programmer wants.)

Comment: Indeed we don't want end users calling arbitrary functions.  What I am trying to do is use the python data model as a kind of database telling us how to map user requests to back-end functionality. But the two things are so similar, that I shouldn't be surprised if python doesn't support it.  I'll accept your answer soon if I don't see a better one.