# How to retrieve function or method signature of local environment without function call

Tags: python, signature

Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545857/check-python-function-signature-without-a-call), but I'm not able to translate the solution (i.e. use `inspect`) in actual code. In addition, the cited question is 5 years old and new methodologies might have become available.

locals() is concise and great, but it returns a dictionary that is affected by what happens in the local environment. However, the solution should be independent on what's going on in the local environment.

```
def foo(a=1):
    return locals()
foo()  # returns {'a': 1}


def bar(a=1):
    a = 2
    return locals()
bar()  # returns {'a': 2}


def solution(a=1):
    a = 2
    return # DO: RETURN SOMETHING
solution()  # should returns {'a': 1}
```

Comment: Whats wrong with `inspect.signature`?

Comment: It requires to pass a callable

Comment: what's wrong with passing a callable?

Comment: I'll need to get signature in the same way for many asynchronous callback methods. If I had to specify the callable for every method, I could mistakenly provide the wrong callable. You could argue that unit-testing will avoid this sort of errors. I argue that the solution to this question will allow to reduce the number of tests and will make the mode cleaner since there is strictly less logic (no callables).