# Can't get argspec for Python callables?

Tags: python, reflection, inspection

I'm playing with Python callable. Basically you can define a python class and implement `__call__` method to make the instance of this class callable. e.g.,

```
class AwesomeFunction(object):
    def __call__(self, a, b):
        return a+b
```

Module inspect has a function getargspec, which gives you the argument specification of a function. However, it seems I cannot use it on a callable object:

```
fn = AwesomeFunction()
import inspect
inspect.getargspec(fn)
```

Unfortunately, I got a TypeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/inspect.py", line 803, in getargspec
    raise TypeError('arg is not a Python function')
TypeError: arg is not a Python function
```

I think it's quite unfortunate that you can't treat any callable object as function, unless I'm doing something wrong here?

Comment: Thank you for reminding me of one of the lesser used and understood magic methods, `__call__`

Answer (score 10):

If you need this functionality, it is absolutely trivial to write a wrapper function that will check to see if `fn` has an attribute `__call__` and if it does, pass its `__call__` function to getargspec.

Answer (score 7):

If you look at the definition of `getargspec` in the [inspect](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/inspect.py?view=markup) module code on svn.python.org. You will see that it calls `isfunction` which itself calls:

```
isinstance(object, types.FunctionType)
```

Since, your `AwesomeFunction` clearly is not an instance of `types.FunctionType` it fails.

If you want it to work you should try the following:

```
inspect.getargspec(fn.__call__)
```

Comment: I know it's expecting a function type. I'm just lamenting the fact that Python didn't design in a way that unifies functions and objects.

Comment: It's mainly because Python isn't an outrageously object-oriented language (Java is my best example). In Java, literally everything is an object, to the point where the smallest unit of runnable source is a class. In Python, since such a paradigm was eschewed, yes, a few features are missing, but it's generally clearer.

Comment: @EnToutCas: Write a proposal/patch.  Might either A) be accepted, or B) shot down with a rationale that demonstrates why it's a bad idea.

Comment: @Nick, good idea. Instead of checking for function type, inspect.getargspec just have to check if the arg has the attribute `__call__`. Although I wouldn't imagine this being accepted as a patch...

Answer (score 0):

`__call__` defines something that can be called by a class instance. You're not giving `getargspec` a valid function because you're passing a class instance to it.

The difference between `__init` and `__call__` is this:

```
fn = AwesomeFunction() # call to __init__
fn(1, 2) # call to __call__
```