# Access variable in nested classes in python

Tags: python

I am new to Python and want to create classes/structures similar to c++ but I have problems understanding what python actually does

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

class innerClass:
    x: int


class outerClass:
    a: innerClass
    b: str
    c: str

test_1 = outerClass()

def setTest(val):
    global test_1
    test_1.x=val


def getTest():
    z=1
    global test_1
    if z==1:
        setTest(z)
    
    return [test_1.x]

getTest()
```

If I change the value of z to `z=0` then it has the following issue

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simplePy.py", line 27, in <module>
    getTest()
  File "simplePy.py", line 25, in getTest
    return [test_1.x]
AttributeError: 'outerClass' object has no attribute 'x'
```

so I have two questions

1. how does it access x with only test_1.x? I would expect it to be
   test_1.a.x as outerClass->innerClass->variable
2. as it worked with `z=1` why does it complain
   about x not being an attribute with `z=0`? I was expecting it to
   return either rubbish value or zero

Comment: You're missing the `@dataclass` decorators.

Comment: You don't need `global test_1`, since neither of the function assigns the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main problem is that `outerClass` has no `x`. You should call `outerClass.inner.x`.

You also forgot to use the dataclass decorator in your classes. Without it, they behave like regular classes and you'd need to define an `__init__`.

Furthermore, the globals are not doing anything. A variable must be defined as `global` if you want to re-assign it, eg `test_1 = None`, but you can re-assign its attributes without the `global` keyword.

Here's my version of the code:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class InnerClass:
    x: int

@dataclass
class OuterClass:
    inner: InnerClass
    a: str
    b: str
    c: str

outter_instance = OuterClass(inner=InnerClass(x=0), a="a", b="b", c="c")

print(outter_instance.inner.x)
outter_instance.inner.x = 5
print(outter_instance.inner.x)
```

Some things I did:

- use the dataclass decorator
- use PascalCase in classes names, which is the standard in Python
- rename some attributes to make them clearer, eg `outter_instance` and `OutClass.inner`
- remove the functions and run everything in the module

Finally, you can also do this without dataclasses:

```py
class InnerClass:
    def __init__(self, x: int):
        self.x = x

class OuterClass:
    def __init__(self, inner: InnerClass, a:str, b:str, c:str):
        self.inner = inner
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

outter_instance = OuterClass(inner=InnerClass(x=0), a="a", b="b", c="c")

print(outter_instance.inner.x)
outter_instance.inner.x = 5
print(outter_instance.inner.x)
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How does it access x with only test_1.x? I would expect it to be test_1.a.x as outerClass->innerClass->variable

When you call `setTest(z)` it creates the `test_1.x` attribute. Python doesn't normally prevent you from creating new attributes in an object (it's possible to prevent this, but it's not the default).

> 2. as it worked with z=1 why does it complain about x not being an attribute with z=0? I was expecting it to return either rubbish value or zero

With `z = 0` you never call `setTest()`, so the `x` attribute is never added to the object. So you get an error when you try to access it.

Comment: can you write an quick line how to access it properly because its still not working
with `test_1.a.x=val` I get `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'x'`

Comment: That means you didn't set `test_1.a` to an `InnerClass` instance. You need `test_1 = OuterClass(InnerClass(0), 0, 0)`

Comment: sorry the previous comment had some code in it but it was messed up, updated the comment :)

Comment: I know, I already answered the updated comment.

Comment: are there anything like default constructors where I don't have to set these values myself?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56665298/how-to-apply-default-value-to-python-dataclass-field-when-none-was-passed