# How to handle default values in parents of python dataclasses

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

This is a simplified version of my code:

```py
@dataclass
class _AbstractDataTableClass:
    """All dataclasses should have a _unique_fields attribute to identify the
    values in that table that must be unique. This assumption simplifies type hints for
    a lot
    of the implemented methods.
    """
    _unique_fields: list[str]

@dataclass
class Order(_AbstractDataTableClass):
    order_id: str
    _unique_fields: list[str] = field(default_factory=lambda: ["order_id"])
```

However when executing I get the error `Attributes without a default cannot follow attributes with one`. I read this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51575931/class-inheritance-in-python-3-7-dataclasses) and understand the problem, but I'm not sure how to find a solution in my case.
I just want to indicate that there is group of classes defined by the parent class of which there will be different subversions, but that python can always expect to find an attribute/property called _unique_fields. Whats the best way to do that?

The only work-around I found so far is this, but I don't have the feeling that this is the most pythonic way.

```py
@dataclass
class _AbstractDataTableClass:

    @property
    def _unique_fields(self) -> list[str]:
        """Property to access the _unique_fields.

        Needed to define this as a property to be able to be able to handle issues 
        related to non-default values in inheritance"""
        return []
    @dataclass
    class Order(_AbstractDataTableClass):
        order_id: str
        _unique_fields: list[str] = field(default_factory=lambda: ["order_id"])
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: It's not exactly the same, but I think you may be able to adapt the solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51575931/class-inheritance-in-python-3-7-dataclasses

Comment: Or here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56665298/how-to-apply-default-value-to-python-dataclass-field-when-none-was-passed

Answer (score 0):

I ended of finding the solution in the other post a bit deeper in the answers. You can read the full answer of Milo Parigi and the comment by Ross Bencina there:
[Class inheritance in Python 3.7 dataclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51575931/class-inheritance-in-python-3-7-dataclasses)

In short, you have to add `kw_only=True` as a parameter to the field object like this:

```py
@dataclass
class _AbstractDataTableClass:
    _unique_fields: list[str]

@dataclass
class Order(_AbstractDataTableClass):
    order_id: str
    _unique_fields: list[str] = field(default_factory=lambda: ["order_id"], kw_only=True)
```