# In python, if missing argument of a parameter the function will work

Tags: python, function, parameters

based on this question... first answer...second code

[Python -- Only pass arguments if the variable exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576553/python-only-pass-arguments-if-the-variable-exists)

is there a way I can handle any number of arguments even it is 12 for example ....

to make more clear...

if I have 10 optional parameter function and user didn't provide one argument or 9 argument it still work

( if A user didn't provide a parameter argument it will ignore that or any other optional arguments
)

thank you ❤

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are talking about [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/). Check this one out.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
def name(arg1, *argv): 
    print ("First argument :", arg1) 
    for arg in argv: 
        print("Next argument through *argv :", arg)

name('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3, 'arg4')
```

Or create multiple functions with the same name but with different amounts of parameters. Then you can call these functions

```
def same_name(oneParam):
     #do something
    
def same_name(oneParam,secondParam):
    #do something else

same_name(oneParam = 'one')
same_name(oneParam = 'one',secondParam = 'two')
```

Comment: look for example the print function in python after you type print function in python it will provide you with a list of parameters ... that exactly what I want

Comment: In my first example, argv is a list of all the parameters entered

Comment: but how can I say if a user entered for example IMAGINE if sky ... it will make the text fly , ground for being floor... how to handle it ... and what if the .... for example   .... for example in a function I make the parameter fly or not fly in 4th parameter and but in my function I defined for example in 3rd parameter....Do You Have a Topic Where I can read ... Just first explain How to the provide me a url where I can read from... your Answer stocked in my mind  ... the second not the first one