# How can I print the function head, including name, arguments, and docstring?

Tags: function, python-3.x

Say I have the following:

```
def foo(arg1, arg2, arg3 = default, *args, *kwargs*):
    """This function is really cool."""
    return
```

How can I define a new function `functionprinter(f)` so that `functionprinter(f)` would print

```
foo(arg1, arg2, arg3 = default, *args, *kwargs*)
This function is really cool.
```

or something of that nature? I already know `foo.__name__` and `foo.__doc__` and have seen the `inspect` module, specifically here: [Getting method parameter names in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218616/getting-method-parameter-names-in-python) but can't seem to string together everything, in particular having the default arguments print properly. I am using Python 3.4.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup! You can with the [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/inspect.html#) module:

```
import inspect

def foo(arg1, arg2, arg3=None , *args, **kwargs):
    """This function is really cool."""
    return

def functionprinter(f):

    print("{}{}".format(f.__name__, inspect.signature(f)))
    print(inspect.getdoc(f))

functionprinter(foo)
```

Prints:

> foo(arg1, arg2, arg3=None, *args, **kwargs)
>   This function is really cool.

Note that I changed your `default` argument to `None` just for this demonstration because I didn't have the variable `default` defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`inspect.signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#introspecting-callables-with-the-signature-object) (to represents the call signature of a callable object and its return annotation.) and `inspect.getdoc` :

```
>>> print(inspect.signature(foo))
(arg1, arg2, arg3=3, *args, **kwargs)
>>> inspect.getdoc(foo)
'This function is really cool.'

>>> print ('\n'.join((foo.__name__+str(inspect.signature(foo)),inspect.getdoc(foo))))
foo(arg1, arg2, arg3='', *args, **kwargs)
This function is really cool.
```