# Is it possible to get a list of all the keyword arguments of a built-in function?

Tags: python

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/218709/2687324, it is possible to use the [inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) module to get the parameter names of Python methods. However, when I tried it with built-in functions:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getargspec(max)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\python\Python27\lib\inspect.py", line 816, in getargspec
    raise TypeError('{!r} is not a Python function'.format(func))
TypeError: <built-in function max> is not a Python function
```

Is there a way to programmatically get the parameter names of built-in Python functions?