# Why can't I see the arguments to the print function imported from future?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, printing

I noticed that I cannot use flush with the new python function after I import it using `from __future__ import print_function`. In my journey to discover why I discovered I can't even inspect what arguments/parameters it takes. Why is it?

1. First I made sure that the inspect function worked.
2. Then I made sure that the print function was indeed a function.
3. After those two (seemed to pass/check) I tried to inspect it but this failed and returned a weird error.

here is what I did:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import inspect

def f(a, b=1):
    pass

#print( print_function )
print( inspect.getargspec( f ) )
g = print
print('what is print: ', print)
print('what is g=print: ', g)
print( inspect.getargspec( g ) )
#print( inspect.getargspec( print ) )

#print('Hello', flush=True)
```

and everything passed except inspecting print:

```
ArgSpec(args=['a', 'b'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=(1,))
what is print?  <built-in function print>
what is g=print?  <built-in function print>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "print_future.py", line 16, in <module>
    print( inspect.getargspec( g ) )
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 816, in getargspec
    raise TypeError('{!r} is not a Python function'.format(func))
TypeError: <built-in function print> is not a Python function
```

Why is that happening?

---

This is some info of my python and system:

```
Python 2.7.11 (default, Jun 24 2016, 21:50:11)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: seems I found something useful: http://bugs.python.org/issue6905

Comment: I read it but I don't understand why C functions are free to treat things as *args and *kwargs:

`This is not an issue, but a fundamental restriction of what getargspec()
can do.  C function signatures are not introspectable, because basically
every C function can be thought of as defined as either

  def func(*args)

or 

  def func(*args, **kwargs)

and is free to do what it wants with the args and kwargs.`

Comment: As the docs say, `inspect` only works on pure Python code, whereas a lot of the builtins are implemented in C. Also asking an unclear follow-up question as a comment probably isn't a great idea.

Answer (score 2):

Extracted from [signature](https://funcsigs.readthedocs.io/en/0.3/#signature):

> Note
>
> Some callables may not be introspectable in certain implementations of
>   Python. For example, in CPython, built-in functions defined in C
>   provide no metadata about their arguments.

I've posted the signature docs because [inspect.getargspec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec) is deprecated since 3.0

Comment: why doesn't it provide docs/info for C stuff? I don't understand the *why*

Comment: @CharlieParker because it uses Python introspection, which doesn't work on C, because C isn't Python.

Answer (score 1):

The `flush` keyword was added to print() in 3.3.

C functions do not normally carry with them the information needed for introspection.  That is simply a fact of how C is defined and compiled.  As a substitute, signatures were added to their docstrings.  IDLE calltips fall back to the docstring if inspect does not work.

In 3.4, a new mechanism was added to include a signature attribute with C-coded function.  The new inspect.signature uses it when present.  Some C-coded functions have been to converted to include the new attribute, many have not.