# How to get function name, function params

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have the following code:

```
run_in_background (
    update_contacts(data={'email': email,'access_token': g.tokens['access_token']})
)
```

And I have created this function to process the called function in the background:

```
def run_in_background(function):

    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_in_executor(None, **function**, **data**)
```

How would I retrieve the function and the data that's being passed to it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting method parameter names in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218616/getting-method-parameter-names-in-python)

Comment: that is being passed how? the funciton parameter in the `run_in_background`?

Comment: @Netwave correct -- though I don't think the function itself will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a decorator!

A decorator is a wrapper that takes a function as it's argument:

```
def decorate(func):

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # *args and **kwargs are input vars passed to func() on its call
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@decorate
def func(arg1, arg2, **kwargs):
    #do_things
```

In your case, this would look like:

```
def run_in_background(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        # remember, data is in *args (or **kwargs if it's a keyword arg)
        loop.run_in_executor(None, func, data)
        return None
    return wrapper

@run_in_background
# data is an arg or positional arg here, but could easily be data=data
def update_contents(data):
    # function logic
```

## Edit: Not always a background process:

You could change your decorator to switch between background and not:

```
def run_in_background(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if background:
            # run in background
        else:
            func(data)
        return None
    return wrapper

@run_in_background
def update_contact(data, background=False):
    #contact func logic
```

That will allow you to keep your decorator and reduce code duplication, while giving you the flexibility to specify if you want a background process or not

Comment: thanks for this response. I like the decorator approach, but sometimes I will be calling the function directly (not in the background), so how could I decorate the specific call?

Comment: For example, if I call it like `run_in_background (
            update_contacts(data={'email': email,'access_token': g.tokens['access_token']})
        )`, it still runs 'synchronously'.

Comment: @DavidL See my edit. if you add a `kwarg` flagging it as a background process, you can just make that code change in the decorator

Comment: thanks for the update, I see how it works now. is there a way to call it directly, like I have it in the statement above, without using a decorator?

Comment: You would just call `update_contact(data)`, the other call is implicit. The decorator in this case will work like `decorator(update_contact(*args, **kwargs))`, even though you've called `update_contact`

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work in the background -- I put a time.sleep(10) in the function to see if it's actually running in the background.

Comment: Note `background` defaults to `False`, you'll have to specify it to be a background process

Comment: thanks, I've accepted that answer, thanks for your help. I've asked another question specifically about how to call it as specified above -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53368394/put-function-in-the-background