# Getting list of parameter names inside python function

Tags: python, parameters

Is there an easy way to be inside a python function and get a list of the parameter names?

For example:

```
def func(a,b,c):
    print magic_that_does_what_I_want()

>>> func()
['a','b','c']
```

Thanks

Answer (score 486, accepted):

Well we don't actually need `inspect` here.

```
>>> func = lambda x, y: (x, y)
>>> 
>>> func.__code__.co_argcount
2
>>> func.__code__.co_varnames
('x', 'y')
>>>
>>> def func2(x,y=3):
...  print(func2.__code__.co_varnames)
...  pass # Other things
... 
>>> func2(3,3)
('x', 'y')
>>> 
>>> func2.__defaults__
(3,)
```

Comment: that'd be `func.func_code.co_varnames[:func.func_code.co_argcount]` since co_varnames is a tuple of all variables present in the function

Comment: In python3 this would be func.__code__.co_varnames

Comment: This only works for non 'builtin_function_or_method'.

Comment: @mikeschuldt Updated answer for Python3

Comment: I suppose it's better `inspect` for Python 2/3 compatibility.

Comment: I use Python 2.7.8, and `__code__` seems to be backported. `func_code` also still works.

Comment: It will not work with function produced with functools.partial. For these you need to look at f.func and remove f.keyword and f.args.

Comment: @Def_Os - `__code__` was introduced in Python 2.6, released in October 2008. 3.0 came out in December 2008. So I wouldn't say it was "backported" - 3.0 branched off of 2.6. The only version with features that were backported from 3 is 2.7.

Comment: __code__ is 2.6-3.X compatible, so is fairly portable

Comment: Please use inspect. Otherwise, your code doesn't work well with functools.wraps in 3.4+. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147816/preserving-signatures-of-decorated-functions

Comment: `func.func_code.co_varnames[:func.func_code.co_argcount]` excludes any keyword-only arguments, i.e. for a function defined as `def f(a, b, *, c, d):` this will only return `('a', 'b')`.

Answer (score 300):

[`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals) returns a dictionary with local names:

```
def func(a, b, c):
    print(locals().keys())
```

prints the list of parameters. If you use other local variables those will be included in this list. But you could make a copy at the beginning of your function.

Comment: `print locals().keys()` will return `['arg']`. I used `print locals.get('arg')`

Comment: @Droogans please check again.  The solution from @unbeknown prints `['a', 'b', 'c']` (possibly not in a-b-c order), as expected. Your solution (a) doesn't work, raises an `AttributeError` -- maybe you meant `print locals().get('arg')`? and (b) if that's what you were trying to do, that prints the value of the parameter, not the name of the parameter as the OP requested.

Comment: Thank you! I have a new love for `"found {thing} in {place}, took {action}, resulting in {result}".format(**locals())` instead of  `"found {thing} in {place}, took {action}, resulting in {result}".format(thing=thing, place=place, action=action, result=result)`

Comment: watch out, `locals()` returns namespace vars too, eg `def func(a,b,c): d=4; print(locals()['d'])`

Comment: @BrunoBronosky why not just use f-strings? `f'found {thing} in {place}, took {action}, resulting in {result}'`

Comment: You can also identically replace `locals()` with `vars()`.

Comment: @speedstyle f-strings were introduced in Python 3.6. The comment was from 3.5. (And yes, f-strings are waay better :D )

Comment: "But you could make a copy at the beginning of your function." - This doesn't help , at least in 3.x; the names of local variables are determined at compile time, and `locals()` will contain them all.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel. I tried the solution in Python 3.11 and it works ok.: `def func(a, b, c): args = locals(); d = 55; print(args); print(locals())` prints `args` only with `a`, `b`,`c`, but `locals` printed at the end includes `d` and also `args`. So, making a copy at the beginning seems to work.

Answer (score 197):

If you also want the values you can use the `inspect` module

```
import inspect

def func(a, b, c):
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    args, _, _, values = inspect.getargvalues(frame)
    print 'function name "%s"' % inspect.getframeinfo(frame)[2]
    for i in args:
        print "    %s = %s" % (i, values[i])
    return [(i, values[i]) for i in args]

>>> func(1, 2, 3)
function name "func"
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
```

Comment: [Kelly Yancey's blog](http://kbyanc.blogspot.com/2007/07/python-aggregating-function-arguments.html) has a great post explaining this in detail and giving a slightly more refined version, plos a comparison with, e.g. unbeknown's solution. Recommended.

Comment: what about `def foo(first, second, third, *therest):`?

Comment: how to use this functionality in a decorator?

Comment: @JDOaktown a decorator function/class takes a function/class as its argument. Therefore, given a python 3 decorator function `def decorate(fn): ...`, you would simply do `fn_params = inspect.signature(fn).parameters` in the decorator and use logic to get the argument values in `fn`'s wrapper, `def wrapper(*args, **kwargs): ...`, which is returned by the decorator.

Answer (score 156):

```
import inspect

def func(a,b,c=5):
    pass

>>> inspect.getargspec(func)  # inspect.signature(func) in Python 3
(['a', 'b', 'c'], None, None, (5,))
```

so for getting arguments list alone use:

```
>>> inspect.getargspec(func)[0]
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: That's not inside the function..

Comment: you can do it inside the function too

Comment: this is actually better, since it shows how to get at parameters of  method you didn't write yourself.

Comment: How can this be done _inside_ the function, though?

Comment: "defaults is a tuple of default argument values or None if there are no default arguments; if this tuple has n elements, they correspond to the last n elements listed in args." documentation

Comment: @UnverifiedContact Just do it inside the function :-). You can access the function name with no problem (ie recursion) so `inspect.getargspec(func)` from within `func` should work just fine

Comment: @DavidC Updated link [`inspect.signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature)