# Python arguments as a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, arguments

How can I get argument names and their values passed to a method as a dictionary?

I want to specify the optional and required parameters for a GET request as part of a HTTP API in order to build the URL. I'm not sure of the best way to make this pythonic.

Comment: Post some code to illustrate, this could mean several things (or perhaps just two).

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/196997/590177

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you list the keyword arguments a Python function receives?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196960/can-you-list-the-keyword-arguments-a-python-function-receives)

Comment: "I’m wanting to wanting to specify the optional and required parameters for a GET request"? Can you expand on this?  It makes very little sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a list/tuple/dict of the arguments passed to a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521901/get-a-list-tuple-dict-of-the-arguments-passed-to-a-function)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use a single argument prefixed with `**`.

```
>>> def foo(**args):
...     print(args)
...
>>> foo(a=1, b=2)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: And just to add, a single * is used to accept an unnamed amount of non keyword args as a list:  *args

Comment: @Marcin: Well, maybe I give away code too easily, but this is the kind of construct that I personally always find hard to search for when learning a language.

Comment: What if I still want the possible keyword arguments (and defaults) to be provided in the function's definition?

Answer (score 54):

For *non-keyworded* arguments, use a single `*`, and for *keyworded* arguments, use a `**`.

For example:

```
def test(*args, **kwargs):
    print args
    print kwargs

>>test(1, 2, a=3, b=4)
(1, 2)
{'a': 3, 'b': 4}
```

Non-keyworded arguments would be unpacked to a tuple and keyworded arguments would be unpacked to a dictionary. 
[Unpacking Argument Lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

Comment: The result would be: `(1, 2)`
`{'a': 3, 'b': 4}`.