# PyGithub search qualifiers, how to use

Tags: python, github, github-api, pygithub

I'm looking to do a search of github users using the PyGithub library function:

```
github.search_users('Keyword', qualifiers = {'location':'San Francisco})
```

The documentation says:

```
search_users(query, sort=NotSet, order=NotSet, **qualifiers)
Calls:  
GET /search/users

Parameters: 
query – string
sort – string (‘followers’, ‘repositories’, ‘joined’)
order – string (‘asc’, ‘desc’)
qualifiers – keyword dict query qualifiers
```

What am I doing wrong in using the qualifiers? When I just have a keyword it works perfectly but when I add any qualifier it stops returning any search results. (I've double checked that results actually match this query using github advanced search.

Comment: Have you tried using `curl` to construct the API query and seeing what that returns? This way you can determine whether there is a problem in PyGithub or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try calling it like

```
github.search_users('Keyword', location='San Francisco')
```

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954746/python-arguments-as-a-dictionary) post to get the idea of how to use args when they're expected as qualifiers.