# python version of javascript's arguments object - does it exist?

Tags: javascript, python, function, arguments

In JavaScript each function has a special `arguments` predefined objects which holds information about arguments passed to the function call, e.g.

```
function test() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  console.log(args);
}
```

arguments can be easily dumped to a standard array:

```
test()
// []

test(1,2,3)
// [1, 2, 3]

test("hello", 123, {}, [], function(){})
// ["hello", 123, Object, Array[0], function]
```

I know that in Python I can use standard arguments, positional arguments and keyword arguments (just like defined [here](http://symfony-world.blogspot.com/2013/07/python-positional-arguments-and-keyword.html)) to manage dynamic parameter number - but is there anything similar to `arguments` object in Python?

Comment: No.  Like you said, the closest thing is varargs like `*args` and `**kwargs`, but those only give you "extra" arguments, not all arguments.  There is somewhat less need for `arguments` in Python because (unlike Javascript) it's not possible to call a function with the wrong number of arguments (i.e., if a function requires two arguments, calling it with just one will give an error).  What do you want to accomplish that makes you want to use something like `arguments`?

Comment: @BrenBarn I was trying to implement all memoization techniques in python (basing on javascript patterns). In JS you make heavy use of `arguments`, e.g. you can make a standard `memoize` function with one parameter (which is a function to be memoized) which will return closured memoized function. This is done using `arguments`, as you can see [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/implementing-memoization-in-javascript/) (see chapter automatic memoization).

Comment: Instead of trying to copy JavaScript patterns, look around for examples of memoization in Python.  In Python you can make a memoize decorator which can be used similarly to the sort of JS function you describe.  Googling "Python memoize" will give you lots of ideas.

Comment: Anyway, in Python there's nothing like `arguments`, as I can see. Thanks.

Comment: Fortunately, I found a duplicate of this question: [Get a list/tuple/dict of the arguments passed to a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521901/get-a-list-tuple-dict-of-the-arguments-passed-to-a-function)

Answer (score 2):

It doesnt exist as is in python but you can call locals() as the first thing in the function and at that point it should only have the arguments

```
>>> def f(a,b):
...    args = locals()
...    for arg, value in args.items():
...        print arg, value
...    return a*b
...
```

Comment: That is true, but if the function has varargs you'll just get them as a tuple/dict, not combined "flat" with the regular arguments.