# How to print function arguments?

Tags: python, function

Let's say I have this function

```
def family():
    S = dict(eyes='hazel', hair='ash')
    N = dict(eyes='blue', hair='blonde')
    K = dict(eyes='brown', hair='ash')
    print()
family()
```

How do I make the function print based on the argument in the parentheses?
for example if i enter
`family(S)`

I want the S dictionary to print and so forth. How would I do this?
Thanks

Comment: The question title, makes me think that this would be a more appropriate answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2521937/6282058

Comment: i dont understand what that is doing

Comment: `locals()` returns a dictionary mapping function argument names to their values. From your question, it wasn't clear whether you would like to print function arguments and values as a dictionary (e.g. `def family(eyes, hair) ...` and `family(eyes='hazel', hair='ash') -> {'eyes': 'hazel', 'hair': 'ash'}`