# How to check if a particular argument is supported in parser.parse_args()?

Tags: python, argparse, args

For example, How can I know whether there is an argument like `args.manual_selection` in `args` (`args = parser.parse_args()`)

Comment: Try this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521901/get-a-list-tuple-dict-of-the-arguments-passed-to-a-function

Comment: During debugging include a `print(args)` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it would be just to convert args to a dictionary

`args = vars(parser.parse_args())`

Then you can check for the existence of the key, e.g.

`args.get("manual_selection", False)`

If that returns `False`, the key does not exist. Of course the default returned for non-existence must not overlap with valid user input.