# How to collate the arguments features to create a set of values from an Enum?

Tags: python, class, object, enums, set

Given an `Enum` object that cannot be modified, and a custom `Query` class that should generate a compilation of the `Enum` values given different arguments:

```
from enum import Enum

class Fields(Enum):
    a = ["hello", "world"]
    b = ["foo", "bar", "sheep"]
    c = ["what", "the"]
    d = ["vrai", "ment", "cest", "vrai"]
    e = ["foofoo"]

class Query:
    def __init__(self, a=True, b=True, c=False, d=False, e=False):
        self.query_fields = set()
        self.query_fields.update(Fields.a.value) if a else None
        self.query_fields.update(Fields.b.value) if b else None
        self.query_fields.update(Fields.c.value) if c else None
        self.query_fields.update(Fields.d.value) if d else None
        self.query_fields.update(Fields.e.value) if e else None
```

It's possible to get a custom set of `query_fields`, as such:

[out]:

```
>>> x = Query()
>>> x.query_fields
{'bar', 'foo', 'hello', 'sheep', 'world'}

>>> x = Query(e=True)
>>> x.query_fields
{'bar', 'foo', 'foofoo', 'hello', 'sheep', 'world'}
```

**Question:** In the `Query` initialization function, we had to iterate through each class argument and do something like `self.query_fields.update(Fields.a.value) if a else None`, **are there other ways to achieve the same behavior and output of `Query().query_fields` without hard-coding each argument**?

Comment: Looking out if there's other ways to get the effect without using *args. Otherwise the bounty goes to Ethan

Comment: In `Query.__init__` do you want each member name present?  In other words, `Query` will only work with `Fields`?

Comment: Query's init should not only work with Fields type, it should be able to take other types. E.g. maybe there's an `f` variable of str type.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment -- could you add an example to your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a more general solution, see below; for a solution for `Fields` specifically and which doesn't need `*args` (or `*members` as the case may be...) check out [Tomer Shetah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66211557/208880).

---

*General Solution*

To make `Query` more generalized and usable with other Enums, I would specify which `Field` members you wanted:

```
class Query:
    #
    def __init__(self, *members):
        self.query_fields = set()
        for member in members:
            self.query_fields.update(member.value)
```

and in use:

```
>>> x = Query()
>>> x.query_fields
set()


>>> y = Query(Fields.a, Fields.c)
>>> y.query_fields
{'world', 'the', 'hello', 'what'}
```

If your defaults are common, you can put them in another variable and use that:

```
>>> fields_default = Fields.a, Fields.b

>>> z = Query(*fields_default)
>>> z.query_fields
{'foo', 'bar', 'world', 'hello', 'sheep'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over Fields to get all the elements, and then use that .name or .value to get the respective attribute.

```
from enum import Enum


class Fields(Enum):
    a = ["hello", "world"]
    b = ["foo", "bar", "sheep"]
    c = ["what", "the"]
    d = ["vrai", "ment", "cest", "vrai"]
    e = ["foofoo"]


class Query:

    defaults = [True, True, False, False, False]

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.query_fields = set()

        for attr, default in zip(Fields, self.defaults):
            if attr.name in kwargs:
                if kwargs[attr.name]:
                    self.query_fields.update(attr.value)
            elif default:
                self.query_fields.update(attr.value)


x = Query()
print(x.query_fields)

x = Query(a=False, e=True)
print(x.query_fields)
```

Note that the number of elements in fields and their order **is** hardcoded in Query.defaults, but I dont think it makes sense for that not to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

After reading [Get a list/tuple/dict of the arguments passed to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2521937/2359227) I figured out it can be achieved without using `*args`.

There is the short version:

```
class Query:
    def __init__(self, a=True, b=True, c=False, d=False, e=False):
        self.query_fields = set()
        local_variables = locals()
        [self.query_fields.update(Fields[local].value) for local in local_variables if local_variables[local] is True]
```

or the more verbose option:

```
class Query:
    def __init__(self, a=True, b=True, c=False, d=False, e=False):
        self.query_fields = set()
        local_variables = locals()
        for local in local_variables:
            if local_variables[local] is True:
                self.query_fields.update(Fields[local].value)
```

The output in both implementations for:

```
x = Query()
print(x.query_fields)
```

is:

```
{'hello', 'foo', 'bar', 'sheep', 'world'}
```

and for:

```
x = Query(e = True)
print(x.query_fields)
```

is:

```
{'foo', 'hello', 'sheep', 'foofoo', 'bar', 'world'}
```