# Python list function argument names

Tags: python, function, arguments

Is there a way to get the parameter names a function takes?

```
def foo(bar, buz):
    pass

magical_way(foo) == ["bar", "buz"]
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582056/getting-list-of-parameters-inside-python-function, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218616/getting-method-parameter-names-in-python

Comment: Maybe one more is warranted, since I spent a good half an hour trying to Google this without hitting those dupes.

Comment: This is the first hit on Google now, thanks to the way OP asked the question. Making answers easier to find by framing the question better is definitely relevant to UX of those looking for answers.

Comment: Btw. I have since learned that it's wrong to say "argument" here, as receiving variables are **parameters**, not arguments.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Use the [inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) module from Python's standard library (the cleanest, most solid way to perform introspection).

Specifically, [inspect.getargspec](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec)`(f)` returns the names *and default values* of `f`'s arguments -- if you only want the names and don't care about special forms `*a`, `**k`,

```
import inspect

def magical_way(f):
    return inspect.getargspec(f)[0]
```

completely meets your expressed requirements.

Comment: you can also use `return inspect.getargspec(f).args`

Comment: @gnibbler, true, in Python 2.6 or better only (so **not** if you're using Python with App Engine (or apps embedding Python 2.5 or earlier); I gave the approach that works in any Python (since 2.1 when `inspect` was added to the standard library).

Comment: maybe you can edit this since getargspec is now deprecated and inspect.signature() is favored instead

Comment: inspect.getargspec is deprecated as of Python 3.6. Instead one should use inspect.signature. Any one knows how to use it?, thanks

Comment: @juanIsaza `inspect.signature(f).parameters`

Comment: You can also inspect a constructor's arguments using "inspect.getargspec(MyClass.__init__)[0]" as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36849919/367544

Comment: that function name tho

Comment: @juanIsaza alternative you can use inspect.getfullargspec(f).args or inspect.getfullargspec(f)[0] (python 3.7)

Answer (score 19):

```
>>> import inspect
>>> def foo(bar, buz):
...     pass
... 
>>> inspect.getargspec(foo)
ArgSpec(args=['bar', 'buz'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
>>> def magical_way(func):
...     return inspect.getargspec(func).args
... 
>>> magical_way(foo)
['bar', 'buz']
```

Comment: Note that `.args` only works in Python 2.6 and up. For older verions you have to use `[0]` instead.

Comment: +1 for providing the `magical_way()` function.