# Dir function in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand few methods while using the dir function..

For example while I execute the following command, it lists the following methods. Any method that starts with `__` is a builtin method for `int` object, but how do I use the other functions like `bit_length`, `conjugate`, in case of `real` I use it as `i.real` and for `bit_lenghth` I use it as `i.bit_length()`.

How do I identify when to use as a attribute (real) and when to use as method call (`bit_length()`):

```
>>> i=0
>>>
>>> dir(i)
['__abs__', '__add__', '__and__', '__class__', '__cmp__', '__coerce__', '__delat
tr__', '__div__', '__divmod__', '__doc__', '__float__', '__floordiv__', '__forma
t__', '__getattribute__', '__getnewargs__', '__hash__', '__hex__', '__index__',
'__init__', '__int__', '__invert__', '__long__', '__lshift__', '__mod__', '__mul
__', '__neg__', '__new__', '__nonzero__', '__oct__', '__or__', '__pos__', '__pow
__', '__radd__', '__rand__', '__rdiv__', '__rdivmod__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_
ex__', '__repr__', '__rfloordiv__', '__rlshift__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__ro
r__', '__rpow__', '__rrshift__', '__rshift__', '__rsub__', '__rtruediv__', '__rx
or__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', '_
_truediv__', '__trunc__', '__xor__', 'bit_length', 'conjugate', 'denominator', '
imag', 'numerator', 'real']
```

Comment: Usually by reading the documentation; calling something that might be a method without knowing what it's supposed to do sounds like a bad idea in any case. `help(i.bit_length)` or `help(i)`.

Answer (score 5):

Methods are attributes *too*. They are just *callable* attributes.

You can test if something is callable using the builtin [`callable()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#callable):

```
>>> 1 .bit_length
<built-in method bit_length of int object at 0x7fe7b2c13118>
>>> callable(1 .bit_length)
True
>>> callable(1 .real)
False
```

Comment: I think you might want to mention that classes are callable as well, but calling the class results in constructing an instance of the class. :)

Comment: +1, I did't know [`callable()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#callable). Docs: *"class instances are callable if they have a __call__() method."*

Comment: @J0HN: `int` is callable too, so are all 'factories'. Meta classes are callable, they produce new classes, etc. And when called they produce return a new object, but so can many functions. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `something` is a function using [`hasattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr)

```
hasattr(something, '__call__')
```

Answer (score 0):

Methods has `__call__` attribute, so in order to determine if something is callable use:

```
hasattr(val, '__call__')
```

The problem is that methods can has arguments, so you'll have to inspect the parameter list (e.g. using something like in [Python list function argument names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517892/python-list-function-argument-names) SO question)