# Introspecting arguments from the constructor function __init__ in Python

Tags: python, oop, arguments, introspection

What is a way to extract arguments from `__init__` without creating new instance.
The code example:

```
class Super:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

I am looking something like `Super.__dict__.keys()`type solution. Just to retrieve name argument information without adding any values. Is there such an option to do that?

Comment: Question is not clear. Do you mean you want to check value of name and decide if you want to create new instance or not?

Comment: I don't want to create instance at all. I want to introspect objects arguments. It is just like question "what arguments this object have". It is all about general introspection not about values. I changed question to make it a bit more understandable.

Comment: Instance is already created by the time `__init__` gets called. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/pythons-use-of-new-and-init

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Update for Python 3.3+ (as pointed out by [beeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3446439/beeb) in the comments)**

You can use [`inspect.signature`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/inspect.html#introspecting-callables-with-the-signature-object) introduced in Python 3.3:

```
class Super:
    def __init__(self, name, kwarg='default'):
        print('instantiated')
        self.name = name

>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.signature(Super.__init__)
<Signature (self, name, kwarg='default')>
```

**Original answer below**

You can use [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html)

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getargspec(Super.__init__)
ArgSpec(args=['self', 'name'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
>>>
```

Edit: `inspect.getargspec` doesn't actually create an instance of `Super`, see below:

```
import inspect

class Super:
    def __init__(self, name):
        print 'instantiated'
        self.name = name

print inspect.getargspec(Super.__init__)
```

This outputs:

```
### Run test.a ###
ArgSpec(args=['self', 'name'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
>>>
```

Note that `instantiated` never got printed.

Comment: It looks like that it is what I was looking for. One additional question: Is there an option to get that result without "inspect" module. Something like Super.__dict__.keys solution if it is not, that means that inspect.getargspec() is like instance simulation that helps to retrieve arguments?

Comment: There are a bunch of answers for retrieving argument names out of a function - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582056/getting-list-of-parameter-names-inside-python-function and it looks like inspect is the only way. Even using `globals` returns in a function call, which is not what you want. Incidentally, using `inspect` doesn't result in a function call, editing my answer for an example...

Comment: @Bahrom anyway to do this for a hierarchy of inheriting classes?

Comment: @VeltzerDoron I'll take a look when I get home

Comment: Actually, I already implemented it by travelling up the class.mro() and getting the __init__ signature along the way,  I used it to write a custom JSON encoder that doesn't encode members with default values, works like a charm. :)

Comment: DeprecationWarning: inspect.getargspec() is deprecated since Python 3.0, use inspect.signature() or inspect.getfullargspec()

Answer (score 1):

A metaclass that stores the concrete `__init__` parameters in a class field:

```py
class ParameterReader(ABCMeta):
    def __init__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        parameters = inspect.signature(cls.__init__).parameters
        parameters = {key: value for key, value in parameters.items() if key not in ['self', 'args', 'kwargs']}
        try:
            cls._init_parameters = cls.__bases__[0]._init_parameters.copy()
            cls._init_parameters.update(parameters)
        except AttributeError:
            cls._init_parameters = parameters

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

`_init_parameters` can then be used within the class instance or outside of it:

```py
class Fruit(metaclass=ParameterReader):
    def __init__(self, color):
        print(color)

class Corn(Fruit):
    def __init__(self, size, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print(size)
        print(self._init_parameters)

print(Corn._init_parameters)
```

Producing:

```
{'color': <Parameter "color">, 'size': <Parameter "size">}
```

As well as in instantiation:

```py
Corn(10, 'yellow')
```

Producing:

```
yellow
10
{'color': <Parameter "color">, 'size': <Parameter "size">}
```

Note how this handles using `*args`, `**kwargs` in Corn's __init__ parameters.

---

Also, note the naming [difference between *arguments* and *parameters*](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-is-the-difference-between-arguments-and-parameters).