# How to print __init__ function arguments in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a dictionary of class names residing in module to their constructor args.

Constructor args should also be a dictionary where I will store the default values of the arguments wherever defined.

Any leads will be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

To provide more details about the use case, What I am trying to do here is for all the classes mentioned in the image [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc0pU.png)

I want to get the constructor parameters for e.g. please refer below image
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5jpx.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Introspecting arguments from the constructor function \_\_init\_\_ in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36849837/introspecting-arguments-from-the-constructor-function-init-in-python)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just want the name of the parameters in the signature of your `__init__`.

That is actually quite simple using the [inspect module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html):

**Modern python answer**:

```py
import inspect

signature = inspect.signature(your_class.__init__).parameters
for name, parameter in signature.items():
    print(name, parameter.default, parameter.annotation, parameter.kind)
```

**Outdated answer**

```
import inspect

signature = inspect.getargspec(your_class.__init__)
signature.args # All arguments explicitly named in the __init__ function 
signature.defaults # Tuple containing all default arguments
signature.varargs # Name of the parameter that can take *args (or None)
signature.keywords # Name of the parameter that can take **kwargs (or None)
```

You can map the default arguments to the corresponding argument names like this:

```
argument_defaults = zip(signature.args[::-1], signature.defaults[::-1])
```

Comment: Note that `getargspec` has been deprecated since 3.0. For 2/3 compat code `getfullargspec` should be used, and [`signature()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) if going for modern python only.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though When I try to this code this gives me something like:  ['self']
None
args
kwargs. But it does not print the actual arguments. I may be missing out something here. I updated the question with more details to explain the actual use case.

Comment: `self`is always the first parameter to the `__init__` call. You can just filter it out. Otherwise I do not understand your question.

Comment: You can do `inspect.signature(your_class)`, without the `__init__`, in this case it doesn't list `self`.

Answer (score 3):

Most recently, the following works:

```
import inspect

signature = inspect.signature(yourclass.__init__)

for param in signature.parameters.values():
    print(param)
```

The difference being (compared to the accepted answer), that the `parameters` instance variable needs to be accessed.