# What does this Code do?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm reading through [jQuery's "Plugins/Authoring"](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) though i already wrote a few jQuery-Plugins. Now I see that jQuery has a special way of scoping the methods and calling:

```
(function( $ ){

  var methods = {
    init : function( options ) { // THIS },
    show : function( ) { // IS   },
    hide : function( ) { // GOOD },
    update : function( content ) { // !!! }
  };

  $.fn.tooltip = function( method ) {

    // Method calling logic
    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
    }    

  };

})( jQuery );
```

I understand the concept of what will happen in the end… but how exactly? This part is what confuses me:

```
    // Method calling logic
    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    }
```

Why `Array.prototype.slide.call(argumetns, 1)`? And where does the variable "arguments" come from all of the sudden? Any brief or deeper explanation is much appreciated. It is said, that this is how plugins should be written… so i'd like to know why.

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't arguments the arguments that were passed into a function? A bit like args and kwargs in Python.

Comment: @Matti Python's args and kwargs are quite different from JavaScript's `arguments` as they're manually specified: `def func(abcd, fghi=True, *args, **kwargs)`, `func(43, False, 79, 83, apple='pie', turnips=False)`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582056/getting-list-of-parameters-inside-python-function) for a rough Python equivalent of `arguments`!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### `arguments`

`arguments` is a part of the JavaScript language. I was confused in *exactly* the way you were when I first ran into it; it's not just you. :-) It's an automatic local variable in every function, and is an array-like structure giving you all of the arguments (see Section 10.6 of [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)), e.g.:

```
function foo() {
    var index;

    for (index = 0; index < arguments.length; ++index) {
        alert(arguments[index]);
    }
}
foo("one", "two"); // alerts "one", then alerts "two"
```

When I say `arguments` is array-like, I mean it — it's **not** an Array. Its references to the arguments are *live* (and bidirectional). For instance:

```
function foo(namedArg, anotherNamedArg) {
    alert(namedArg === arguments[0]);        // alerts true, of course
    alert(anotherNamedArg === arguments[1]); // also alerts true
    namedArg = "foo";
    alert(arguments[0]);                     // alerts "foo"
    arguments[0] = "bar";
    alert(namedArg);                         // alerts "bar"
}
```

Note that when assigning a value to `namedArg`, the result is reflected in `arguments[0]`, and vice-versa.

`arguments` is really cool, but only use it if you need to — some implementations speed up calling functions by not hooking it up until/unless the function actually first tries to access it, which can slow the function down (very slightly).

`arguments` also has property on it called `callee`, which is a reference to the function itself:

```
function foo() {
    alert(foo === arguments.callee); // alerts true
}
```

However, it's best to avoid using `arguments.callee` for several reasons. One reason is that in many implementations, it's *really* slow (I don't know why, but to give you an idea, the function call overhead can increase by *an order of magnitude* if you use `arguments.callee`). Another reason is that you can't use it in the new "strict" mode of ECMAScript5.

(Some implementations also had `arguments.caller` — *shudder* — but fortunately it was never widespread and is not standardized anywhere [nor likely to be].)

### The `slice` call and `apply`

Regarding

```
return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
```

What that's doing is using the `Array#slice` method to copy the arguments into an array (minus the first argument, which was the method to call), and then passing the resulting array into the `Function#apply` function on the function instance it's calling. `Function#apply` calls the function instance with the given `this` object and the arguments supplied as an array. The code's not just using `arguments.slice` because (again) `arguments` isn't really an Array and so you can't rely on it having all of the Array functions, but the specification specifically says (in Section 15.4.4.10) that you can apply the `Array.prototype.slice` function to anything that's array-like, and so that's what they're doing.

`Function#apply` and `Function#call` are also built-in parts of JavaScript (see Sections 15.3.4.3 and 15.3.4.4). Here are simpler examples of each:

```
// A function to test with
function foo(msg, suffix) {
    alert(this.prefix + ": " + msg + suffix);
}

// Calling the function without any `this` value will default `this`
// to the global object (`window` on web browsers)
foo("Hi there", "!"); // Probably alerts "undefined: Hi there!" because the
                      // global object probably doesn't have a `prefix` property

// An object to use as `this`
var obj = {
    prefix: "Test"
};

// Calling `foo` with `this` = `obj`, using `call` which accepts the arguments
// to give `foo` as discrete arguments to `call`
foo.call(obj, "Hi there", "!"); // alerts "Test: Hi there!"
      // ^----^-----------^---- Three discrete args, the first is for `this`,
      //                        the rest are the args to give `foo`

// Calling `foo` with `this` = `obj`, using `apply` which accepts the arguments
// to give `foo` as an array
foo.apply(obj, ["Hi there", "!"]); // alerts "Test: Hi there!"
            // ^---------------^---- Note that these are in an array, `apply`
            //                       takes exactly two args (`this` and the
            //                       args array to use)
```

Comment: ppl like you are the reason why i love SO so much.

Answer (score 3):

[`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/functions_and_function_scope/arguments) is a keyword, the arguments passed to the function.  But you don't want *all* of them, since the first you know, it's `method`, so this is taking every argument past the first to use in [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply)...passing those arguments into whichever method was specified in the first `method` argument.

If it can't find `method` (meaning the first argument wasn't `'init'`, `'show'`, `'hide'`, or `'update'`, then it goes to the `else` portion, and passes all the arguments to the `init` method (the default, if you will).

For example:

- `.tooltip({ thing: value })` would call `init({ thing: value })` since that's the default
- `.tooltip('show', var1, var2)` would call `show(var1, var2)`

Answer (score 1):

Variable `arguments` is defined javascript variable. It stores all arguments called in function in array. For example :

```
function variablesCount() {
    alert(arguments.length);
}

variablesCount(var1, var2); // alerts 2
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.slide.call(argumetns, 1)` converts the `arguments` pseudo-array into a real array (skipping the first element).

`arguments` contains all arguments the function you are currently in has been called with. It is automatically provided by JavaScript. Since we need a real array (`arguments` cannot be manipulated, etc.), we convert it to one using this statement.

Answer (score 1):

`arguments` is a special JavaScript variable which means "all the arguments given to this function". It isn't quite an array, but behaves almost like one, so instead of saying `arguments.slice(1)` it calls `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)`; what it's doing it taking all except the first value in the list - for `func(1, 2, 3, 4)` it will be `[2, 3, 4]`.

The end result of this is that when you call `$.fn.tooltip('foo', 'bar', 'baz')` it will try to call `methods['foo']('bar', 'baz')`.