# Python get arguments for partial functions

Tags: python, parameters, arguments, introspection, partial

I am looking to do something similar to what was asked here [Getting list of parameter names inside python function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582056/getting-list-of-parameters-inside-python-function), but using partial functions. ie. I need to get the possible arguments for a partial function. I can get the keyword arguments using:

```
my_partial_func.keywords
```

but I am currently struggling to get the non-keyword arguments. The inspect module also yields nothing for this particular case. Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.args` contains the arguments passed to the partial function. If you want to get the arguments that the original function expects, use the `inspect` solution you linked on the `.func` attribute.

You can find this out by calling `dir` on a functools.partial object:

```
>>> dir(x)
['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'args', 'func', 'keywords']
```

Comment: Thanks, calling inspect on the my_partial_function.func worked