# How do I ask a function for the names of its parameters in Python?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting list of parameters inside python function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582056/getting-list-of-parameters-inside-python-function)

E.g. supposes I have

```
def foo(a, b='B'): return
```

How can I ask foo to tell me that it has required parameter 'a', and parameter 'b', which has 'B' as it's default value?

Comment: You can see it with `help(foo)`

Comment: @JBernardo That works for humans, but how can my programs access that information? Presumably, help uses the mechanism that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`inspect.getargspec`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec).

```
def foo(a, b='B'): pass

import inspect
print inspect.getargspec(foo)
```

It may appear to be unclear which argument the default is for, but since non-default arguments can't follow default arguments, the default has to be for the 2nd argument.

Edit: The linked duplicate is good, an answer there shows you can get the same info without `inspect`, using `func.func_code.co_varnames` and `func.func_defaults` or `func.__defaults__`.

Comment: link
+ explanation of something that is very likely to be unclear
+ alternate solution
= MEGA awesome answer!!! :D